# Replacing diacritics in Javascript

Tags: javascript, diacritics

How can I replace diacritics (ă,ş,ţ etc) with their "normal" form (a,s,t) in javascript?

Comment: Maybe with their unicode character, the function fromCharCode() of String type and the replace function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top This question will be helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to do it entirely on the client side, I think your only option is with some kind of lookup table. Here's a starting point, written by a chap called Olavi Ivask on his [blog](http://olaviivask.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-remove-diacritics-with-javascript/)...

```
function replaceDiacritics(s)
{
    var s;

    var diacritics =[
        /[\300-\306]/g, /[\340-\346]/g,  // A, a
        /[\310-\313]/g, /[\350-\353]/g,  // E, e
        /[\314-\317]/g, /[\354-\357]/g,  // I, i
        /[\322-\330]/g, /[\362-\370]/g,  // O, o
        /[\331-\334]/g, /[\371-\374]/g,  // U, u
        /[\321]/g, /[\361]/g, // N, n
        /[\307]/g, /[\347]/g, // C, c
    ];

    var chars = ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u','N','n','C','c'];

    for (var i = 0; i < diacritics.length; i++)
    {
        s = s.replace(diacritics[i],chars[i]);
    }

    document.write(s);
}
```

You can see this is simply an array of regexes for known diacritic chars, mapping them back onto a "plain" character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings - here is a faster answer

Answer (score 44):

In modern browsers and node.js you can use [unicode normalization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to decompose those characters followed by a filtering regex.

`str.normalize('NFKD').replace(/[^\w]/g, '')`

If you wanted to allow characters such as whitespaces, dashes, etc. you should extend the regex to allow them.

`str.normalize('NFKD').replace(/[^\w\s.-_\/]/g, '')`

```js
var str = 'áàâäãéèëêíìïîóòöôõúùüûñçăşţ';
var asciiStr = str.normalize('NFKD').replace(/[^\w]/g, '');
console.info(str, asciiStr);
```

**NOTES:** This method does not work with characters that do not have unicode composed varian. i.e. `ø` and `ł`

Comment: Best answer so far

Comment: There is a Polish letter `ł` which gets deleted with this solution. You can preserve it be applying additional `.replace(/\u0142/g, "l")` before `normalize()`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have looked a bit further into the topic and yes, there are some characters that do not have a composed form so they get lost after the regex. Sadly there seems like the only option for those characters is a translation table. (I am afraid most of the characters of this list https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=STROKE will be affected by the same problem)

Comment: Where has this answer been all my life? I was actually looking for the lookup table I had used in the past, and found your answer. Thanks much!

Comment: would work on a server or a browser but not ie11.
-i agree; best answer! cheers

Comment: This does not replace `đ` with `d`

Comment: As noted in the answer, this method does not work for characters that do not have unicode composed varian. https://codepoints.net/search?dt=none

Answer (score 27):

A more complete version with case sensitive support, ligatures and whatnot.
Original source at: http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/

```
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
    {'base':'A', 'letters':/[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]/g},
    {'base':'AA','letters':/[\uA732]/g},
    {'base':'AE','letters':/[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]/g},
    {'base':'AO','letters':/[\uA734]/g},
    {'base':'AU','letters':/[\uA736]/g},
    {'base':'AV','letters':/[\uA738\uA73A]/g},
    {'base':'AY','letters':/[\uA73C]/g},
    {'base':'B', 'letters':/[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]/g},
    {'base':'C', 'letters':/[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]/g},
    {'base':'D', 'letters':/[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]/g},
    {'base':'DZ','letters':/[\u01F1\u01C4]/g},
    {'base':'Dz','letters':/[\u01F2\u01C5]/g},
    {'base':'E', 'letters':/[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]/g},
    {'base':'F', 'letters':/[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]/g},
    {'base':'G', 'letters':/[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]/g},
    {'base':'H', 'letters':/[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]/g},
    {'base':'I', 'letters':/[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]/g},
    {'base':'J', 'letters':/[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]/g},
    {'base':'K', 'letters':/[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]/g},
    {'base':'L', 'letters':/[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]/g},
    {'base':'LJ','letters':/[\u01C7]/g},
    {'base':'Lj','letters':/[\u01C8]/g},
    {'base':'M', 'letters':/[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]/g},
    {'base':'N', 'letters':/[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]/g},
    {'base':'NJ','letters':/[\u01CA]/g},
    {'base':'Nj','letters':/[\u01CB]/g},
    {'base':'O', 'letters':/[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]/g},
    {'base':'OI','letters':/[\u01A2]/g},
    {'base':'OO','letters':/[\uA74E]/g},
    {'base':'OU','letters':/[\u0222]/g},
    {'base':'P', 'letters':/[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]/g},
    {'base':'Q', 'letters':/[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]/g},
    {'base':'R', 'letters':/[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]/g},
    {'base':'S', 'letters':/[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]/g},
    {'base':'T', 'letters':/[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]/g},
    {'base':'TZ','letters':/[\uA728]/g},
    {'base':'U', 'letters':/[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]/g},
    {'base':'V', 'letters':/[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]/g},
    {'base':'VY','letters':/[\uA760]/g},
    {'base':'W', 'letters':/[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]/g},
    {'base':'X', 'letters':/[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]/g},
    {'base':'Y', 'letters':/[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]/g},
    {'base':'Z', 'letters':/[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]/g},
    {'base':'a', 'letters':/[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g},
    {'base':'aa','letters':/[\uA733]/g},
    {'base':'ae','letters':/[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3]/g},
    {'base':'ao','letters':/[\uA735]/g},
    {'base':'au','letters':/[\uA737]/g},
    {'base':'av','letters':/[\uA739\uA73B]/g},
    {'base':'ay','letters':/[\uA73D]/g},
    {'base':'b', 'letters':/[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]/g},
    {'base':'c', 'letters':/[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]/g},
    {'base':'d', 'letters':/[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]/g},
    {'base':'dz','letters':/[\u01F3\u01C6]/g},
    {'base':'e', 'letters':/[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g},
    {'base':'f', 'letters':/[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]/g},
    {'base':'g', 'letters':/[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]/g},
    {'base':'h', 'letters':/[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]/g},
    {'base':'hv','letters':/[\u0195]/g},
    {'base':'i', 'letters':/[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g},
    {'base':'j', 'letters':/[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]/g},
    {'base':'k', 'letters':/[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]/g},
    {'base':'l', 'letters':/[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]/g},
    {'base':'lj','letters':/[\u01C9]/g},
    {'base':'m', 'letters':/[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]/g},
    {'base':'n', 'letters':/[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]/g},
    {'base':'nj','letters':/[\u01CC]/g},
    {'base':'o', 'letters':/[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]/g},
    {'base':'oi','letters':/[\u01A3]/g},
    {'base':'ou','letters':/[\u0223]/g},
    {'base':'oo','letters':/[\uA74F]/g},
    {'base':'p','letters':/[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]/g},
    {'base':'q','letters':/[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]/g},
    {'base':'r','letters':/[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]/g},
    {'base':'s','letters':/[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]/g},
    {'base':'t','letters':/[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]/g},
    {'base':'tz','letters':/[\uA729]/g},
    {'base':'u','letters':/[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g},
    {'base':'v','letters':/[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]/g},
    {'base':'vy','letters':/[\uA761]/g},
    {'base':'w','letters':/[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]/g},
    {'base':'x','letters':/[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]/g},
    {'base':'y','letters':/[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]/g},
    {'base':'z','letters':/[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g}
];
var changes;
function removeDiacritics (str) {
    if(!changes) {
        changes = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<changes.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(changes[i].letters, changes[i].base);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A simple modification to the script of Paul. Extend the String-object

```
String.prototype.removeDiacritics = function() {
    var diacritics = [
        [/[\300-\306]/g, 'A'],
        [/[\340-\346]/g, 'a'],
        [/[\310-\313]/g, 'E'],
        [/[\350-\353]/g, 'e'],
        [/[\314-\317]/g, 'I'],
        [/[\354-\357]/g, 'i'],
        [/[\322-\330]/g, 'O'],
        [/[\362-\370]/g, 'o'],
        [/[\331-\334]/g, 'U'],
        [/[\371-\374]/g, 'u'],
        [/[\321]/g, 'N'],
        [/[\361]/g, 'n'],
        [/[\307]/g, 'C'],
        [/[\347]/g, 'c'],
    ];
    var s = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < diacritics.length; i++) {
        s = s.replace(diacritics[i][0], diacritics[i][1]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var wrongString = "hëllô";
alert(wrongString.removeDiacritics()); // alerts "hello"
```

Answer (score 5):

I have ported the Apache Lucene ASCII Folding Filter to JavaScript. You can replace a lot of Unicode characters (including diacritics) to ASCII base forms.

You can find the port on https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii-js

After integrating the library you could fold strings like that:

```json
//foldToASCII("ăşţ"); -> depreciated
```

### Edit

What I did to get this to work was follow the install instructions in his link then import the lib, and then I could use it.

```
import ASCIIFolder from fold-to-ascii

//Then I can call the following:
ASCIIFolder.foldReplacing("Lörem  ëripuît") === "Lorem  eripuit";

//Which results in `ast`.
```

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." I'd strongly suggest editing this answer to show *how* your product/project can be used to solve the problem. As it stands, this veers close to spam territory since it's a link to your Github page, with no other advice, just promotion.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, a full working example would exceed the maximum length for an answer. The body is limited to 30000 characters whereas my example would require 95180 characters. I just tried ;-)
If you have an idea how to make this answer more meaningful don't hesitate to edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider following syntax, where each symbol from value will be replaced with it's key symbol (case-sensitive)

```
var diacritics = {
  a: 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåĀāąĄ',
  c: 'ÇçćĆčČ',
  d: 'đĐďĎ',
  e: 'ÈÉÊËèéêëěĚĒēęĘ',
  i: 'ÌÍÎÏìíîïĪī',
  l: 'łŁ',
  n: 'ÑñňŇńŃ',
  o: 'ÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøŌō',
  r: 'řŘ',
  s: 'ŠšśŚ',
  t: 'ťŤ',
  u: 'ÙÚÛÜùúûüůŮŪū',
  y: 'ŸÿýÝ',
  z: 'ŽžżŻźŹ'
}

function replaceDiacritics(text) {
  for(var toLetter in diacritics) if(diacritics.hasOwnProperty(toLetter)) {
    for(var i = 0, ii = diacritics[toLetter].length, fromLetter, toCaseLetter; i < ii; i++) {
      fromLetter = diacritics[toLetter][i];
      if(text.indexOf(fromLetter) < 0) continue;
      toCaseLetter = fromLetter == fromLetter.toUpperCase() ? toLetter.toUpperCase() : toLetter;
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(fromLetter, 'g'), toCaseLetter);
    }
  }
  return text;
}

replaceDiacritics('ŁÁŘŠÓÑ'); // LARSON
replaceDiacritics('Łąřśøń'); // Larson
```

Comment: What about: function replaceDiacritics(text) {
  return text
    .split('')
    .map(l => Object.keys(diacritics).find(k => diacritics[k].includes(l)) || l)
    .join('');
}

Comment: @Niels I like it!

Answer (score 2):

You would need a conversion map, something like this:

```
function removeAccents(str) {
    var convMap = {
        "ă" : "a",
        "ş" : "s",
        "ţ" : "t"
    }
    for (var i in convMap) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(i, "g"), convMap[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Or if you have access to `iconv` on your box, you could perhaps use some ajax calls to remove the accents with iconv's //TRANSLIT parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This method is a refactor of the first response.

```
function replaceDiacritics(str){

  var diacritics = [
    {char: 'A', base: /[\300-\306]/g},
    {char: 'a', base: /[\340-\346]/g},
    {char: 'E', base: /[\310-\313]/g},
    {char: 'e', base: /[\350-\353]/g},
    {char: 'I', base: /[\314-\317]/g},
    {char: 'i', base: /[\354-\357]/g},
    {char: 'O', base: /[\322-\330]/g},
    {char: 'o', base: /[\362-\370]/g},
    {char: 'U', base: /[\331-\334]/g},
    {char: 'u', base: /[\371-\374]/g},
    {char: 'N', base: /[\321]/g},
    {char: 'n', base: /[\361]/g},
    {char: 'C', base: /[\307]/g},
    {char: 'c', base: /[\347]/g}
  ]

  diacritics.forEach(function(letter){
    str = str.replace(letter.base, letter.char);
  });

  return str;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is ES2020 version of the accepted low-level solution. If You can recall the letters that need to be replaced, create a mapping and use `String.replace()` to map letters one-by-one:

```
const mapping = {
  'ă': 'a',
  'ş': 's',
  'ţ': 't'
}

const replaceDiacritics = s => s.split('').map(letter => mapping[letter] ?? letter).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function replaceDiacritics(text) {     
  const diacr =     "ÁÄČÇĎÉĚËÍŇÓÖŘŠŤÚŮÜÝŽáäčçďéěëíňóöřšťúůüýž";
  const diacrSubs = "AACCDEEEINOORSTUUUYZaaccdeeeinoorstuuuyz";

  if (text.length < diacr.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      let indexOfSpecChar = diacr.indexOf(text[i]);

      if (indexOfSpecChar > -1) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(diacr[indexOfSpecChar], 'g'), diacrSubs[indexOfSpecChar]);
      }

    }
  } else {
    for (let j = 0; j < diacr.length; j++) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(diacr[j], 'g'), diacrSubs[j]);
    }
  }

  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const clean = (text) => {
  return text
    .toLocaleLowerCase("tr")
    .replace(/ı/g, "i")
    .normalize("NFKD")
    .replace(/[^\w]/g, "")
    .normalize("NFKD")
    .replace(/[^\w\s.-_/]/g, "")
    .replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]/g, "")
    .replace(/_/g, "");
};
```

Comment: This code may help you to make a clean search, it removes special characters, emojis, spaces, diacritics... if your language has its own special characters you can use your country code instead 'tr' to convert it to english characters

Comment: Add some info to what this change does, why it is needed etc.