# Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, diacritics

How do I remove accentuated characters from a string? 
Especially in IE6, I had something like this:

```
accentsTidy = function(s){
    var r=s.toLowerCase();
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/\s/g),"");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[àáâãäå]/g),"a");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/æ/g),"ae");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/ç/g),"c");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[èéêë]/g),"e");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[ìíîï]/g),"i");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/ñ/g),"n");                
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[òóôõö]/g),"o");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/œ/g),"oe");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[ùúûü]/g),"u");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[ýÿ]/g),"y");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/\W/g),"");
    return r;
};
```

but IE6 bugs me, seems it doesn't like my regular expression.

Comment: The answers here seem to be ignoring the issue of normalization. For a really robust solution you'd have to look into doing the sorts of things that are carried out by https://github.com/walling/unorm/ .

Comment: @JonathanFingland Some software doesn't allow special characters in an id slot. (HTML PAGE NAMES for example) This is another reason to want to remove them. Keep the title in it's original form but not have to retype all those characters.

Comment: @Mallow your example would be great for validation, but not sanitizing. If the string a user enters has limitations, they need to know that and be asked to re-enter the string with the constraints provided. OP's case is actually just for sorting and not for permanent changes to the data. OP would probably benefit from sorting using the [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method which will allow you sort the strings according to the locale setting of the browser (same reason to use toLocaleString() when working with dates)

Comment: @Jonathan : have you tried to use localeCompare ? "ca".localeCompare("ça") gives me -132 in Chrome. The browser's locale will never tell you that "c" is equal to "ç". And that's very well, since it should not. They are indeed different.

Comment: I delved a bit more into the issue. The specification does not enforce anything regarding the locale (I can't know what the browser will do), but recommends that the browsers transcribe the string into a Unicode Normalized Form (http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms). In this form "ç" is translated into the character 'c' plus the character 'cedilla'. That is not what I want.

Comment: @JonathanFingland I am not sure that would work in my situation since the user's entered title is the required title for the article. It would be unreasonable for me to ask them to edit their title (unless maybe if they were writing articles about coding) But their "C'est la vie." is their title, I need that data, just my structure changes to to "cest_la_vie".. Not sure if I am clear but that's my deal, probably nothing to do with OP

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863800/replacing-diacritics-in-javascript

Comment: This is very useful for searches too. I'm building a search input box - where you type soccer player names from all over the world and I want autocompletion. Guess what in my language there are no diacritics so it's hard for me to type names like 'López' or 'Óscar'

Comment: IE6 issue may be due to the fact that RE original contructor's arguments are expected to be strings _("PATTERN" [, flags])_ `new RegExp("ab+c", "g");` and an already created regexp object [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: This is incorrect since you're only covering some of the accented characters. For example if only count a with diacritics we have a long list "áàăắằẵẳa̧á̧à̧â̧ǎ̧âấầẫẩa̭ǎa̐a̓a̋åǻå̂ää́ä̀ä̂ä̌ǟãã́ã̀a̰ȧȧ́ǡąą́ą̀ą̂ą̌ą̄ą̄́ą̄̀ą̄̂ą̄̌‌​ā̊ą̊ą̃ą̈ą̈̀ą̈̂ą̈̌āā́ā̀ā̂ā̌ā̆ a̱á̱à̱â̱ä̱ā̱å̱ảȁȃạạ́ạ̀ặậạ̄ạ̈ạ̃ḁⱥa̍ᶏɑ̀ɑ̂ɑ̌aᶐ" and it's still not complete list. Moreover the dictionary order is not the same across all languages. For example Czech consider CH a separate character and put it right after H. Some languages like Norwegian put the accented characters "æøå" at the end of the alphabet instead

Comment: In the old days CH is also a separate letter in Spanish alphabet placed after C, so CH will be after CZ. So stripping out all diacritics and sort is not a good way to go.

Comment: @JonathanFingland Here a use case: In http://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC5B9R8_charleroi-pub-crawl-directors-cut there is code used in the enigma with an operation asking to substitute letters by numbers A=1, B=2, C=3, ... then to add each of these numbers. In this code, É will be 5 too, like E.

Comment: The best way would be for everyone to realize that **`a` and `a with something` is still an `a` ...** and remove the whole "*diacritic letters are new letters!*" thing from the world... sadly, I doubt it will be done, but hope dies last...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated and there is a MUCH preferred solution listed below. People may come to this page and actually use that solution. Please update your accepted answer.

Comment: **This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)!** If you are trying to sort strings like `e` < `é` < `f`, then you are performing Unicode [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) — so you should use the (customizable, locale-dependent) [Unicode collation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm), implemented by [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) in JavaScript.

Comment: @Lynn Sure but when the question was asked, I did not know that I should wait for 3 years for the Intl.Collator spec to be defined.

Comment: Given the state JS was in in 2009, you’re not at all in the wrong. But I think very many Googlers will end up here with the same end goal as yours (what other reason is there to remove diacritics?) and it’s worth mentioning to them that `Intl.Collator` now exists to solve the X problem, just as @LewisDiamond mentioned that `normalize('NFD')` now exists to solve the Y problem.

Comment: @Lynn agreed Intl.Collator is probably what the OP was looking for. I added the info to my answer to make sure people have both options depending on what they need.

Comment: @glmxndr why are you doing `new RegExp(/foo/g)` instead of just `/foo/g` (which creates an instance of `RegExp`?

Answer (score 1961, accepted):

With ES2015/ES6 [String.prototype.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize),

```
const str = "Crème Brulée"
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
> "Creme Brulee"
```

Note: use `NFKD` if you want things like `\uFB01`(`ﬁ`) normalized (to `fi`).

Two things are happening here:

1. `normalize()`ing to `NFD` Unicode normal form decomposes combined graphemes into the combination of simple ones. The `è` of `Crème` ends up expressed as `e` +  `̀`.
2. Using a regex [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match the U+0300 → U+036F range, it is now trivial to globally get rid of the diacritics, which the Unicode standard conveniently groups as the [Combining Diacritical Marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) Unicode block.

As of 2021, one can also use [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
```

See comment for performance testing.

**Alternatively, if you just want sorting**

[Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) has sufficient support [~95% right now](https://caniuse.com/#search=intl.collator), a polyfill is also available [here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/) but I haven't tested it.

```
const c = new Intl.Collator();
["creme brulee", "crème brulée", "crame brulai", "crome brouillé",
"creme brulay", "creme brulfé", "creme bruléa"].sort(c.compare)
["crame brulai", "creme brulay", "creme bruléa", "creme brulee",
"crème brulée", "creme brulfé", "crome brouillé"]


["creme brulee", "crème brulée", "crame brulai", "crome brouillé"].sort((a,b) => a>b)
["crame brulai", "creme brulee", "crome brouillé", "crème brulée"]
```

Comment: There is a polyfill available for normalize for the poor souls that cannot use ECMAScript 6. https://github.com/walling/unorm

Comment: here a jsperf with what? https://jsperf.com/normalizeremovediacretics3 it seems to be really fast

Comment: This solution is the only correct solution here. This works on NodeJS 4.6, Firefox 50 and Chrome 54.

Comment: There's always one char that fails..  `'ąśćńżółźćę'.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")` -> `ascnzołzce` (missing match for `ł` -> `l`).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `ł` is a letter in itself, not an accented `L`. Therefore it should not be changed to `l`.

Comment: @PawełFus - the ł does not fall within the character class range. You can target it specifically as `\u0142` ---SO---> `'ł'.replace(/\u0142/g, "l")`

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to point out. Of course you are right, it's a letter, not an accented `L`.

Comment: @PawełFus If you want to sort them, use Intl.Collate with the proper locale. I don't know how that letter sorts in Polish but it should work.

Comment: Be careful, normalize is not supported on all browsers. I had it crash on a React app running on Android, I used instead deburr from lodash

Comment: fyi it will not replace `æø`

Comment: @Binyamin ae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86 and ø https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98 are letters, not accented letters.

Comment: @BlackDog deburr not works with UTF8 strings. Only with latin-1 strings :/

Comment: Just a little more information regarding Unicode Normalization Forms => http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms

Comment: That's a great solution. I see it does not work on all letters (like Polish Ł for example, found more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453284/639956) ). I'd just like to understand the difference between normalizing with NFD vs NFKD. The later seems to be better (checked with this example string '\u1E9B\u0323').

Comment: This does not work for Russian characters `ё` and `й`.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Because those are not diacritics. They are actual letters, even if the writing is similar to diacritics.

Comment: @LewisDiamond I meant that `'ёй'.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')` will return`еи`, but I need `ёй`. It doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Therefore those are diacritics.

Comment: awesome, you saved a lot o time to create a rule to replace all undesireble chars... And don't work nicely at the end

Comment: Just a reminder that the question is "Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript", "Œ", "и", "ł", etc are not accents/diacritics.

Comment: @LewisDiamond, neither `ñ` is an accented character, but it gets converted

Comment: Took me half a day to realize that this method is bogus. It removes non-diacritical letters.

Comment: Is there a Polyfill for `normalize` without using `defineProperty`. I need to implement it within the JS Engine of a legacy Adobe LiveCycle XFA forms platform. When I use any polyfill with `defineProperty` it doesn't work.

Comment: The only real exception that I am aware of with this method is for things like `ẚ` (_LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING_). The reason? Its compatibility decomposition uses **U+02BE** `ʾ` _MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING_, which is outside the range of **U+0300**- **U+036F**.

Comment: Is there a way to DE normalize? I am using this on a tilde character and it's outputting in console as a question mark. How can I convert the character back to what it was previously?

Comment: it does not replace `đ` with `d` .

Comment: Most people probably want to [specify `NFKD` instead of `NFD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#compatibility_normalization)

Comment: I'm joining the party because I wrote the `ubase.js` library which takes care of this. However, there is no unique solution that will please everyone, because "removing accents" is different from "transliterate" and different from "get the base letter". For instance, remove the accent from "Å" should give "A", while transliterate depends on the country, for Denmark this should give "AA". On the other hand, "get the base letter" from "" should clearly give "E", while it is neither a question of accents, diacritics, or transliteration. AFAIK, ubase.js works will all examples in this thread.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, Lewis. I just wanted to let you know that there is also an accent on the 'u' in 'crème brûlée' :-)

Answer (score 280):

I slightly modified khel version for one reason: Every regexp parse/replace will cost O(n) operations, where n is number of characters in target text. But, regexp is not exactly what we need. So:

```js
/*
   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
*/
    var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
        {'base':'A', 'letters':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'},
        {'base':'AA','letters':'\uA732'},
        {'base':'AE','letters':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
        {'base':'AO','letters':'\uA734'},
        {'base':'AU','letters':'\uA736'},
        {'base':'AV','letters':'\uA738\uA73A'},
        {'base':'AY','letters':'\uA73C'},
        {'base':'B', 'letters':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
        {'base':'C', 'letters':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
        {'base':'D', 'letters':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0'},
        {'base':'DZ','letters':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
        {'base':'Dz','letters':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
        {'base':'E', 'letters':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'},
        {'base':'F', 'letters':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
        {'base':'G', 'letters':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
        {'base':'H', 'letters':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
        {'base':'I', 'letters':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
        {'base':'J', 'letters':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
        {'base':'K', 'letters':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
        {'base':'L', 'letters':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
        {'base':'LJ','letters':'\u01C7'},
        {'base':'Lj','letters':'\u01C8'},
        {'base':'M', 'letters':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'},
        {'base':'N', 'letters':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
        {'base':'NJ','letters':'\u01CA'},
        {'base':'Nj','letters':'\u01CB'},
        {'base':'O', 'letters':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'},
        {'base':'OI','letters':'\u01A2'},
        {'base':'OO','letters':'\uA74E'},
        {'base':'OU','letters':'\u0222'},
        {'base':'OE','letters':'\u008C\u0152'},
        {'base':'oe','letters':'\u009C\u0153'},
        {'base':'P', 'letters':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
        {'base':'Q', 'letters':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
        {'base':'R', 'letters':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
        {'base':'S', 'letters':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
        {'base':'T', 'letters':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
        {'base':'TZ','letters':'\uA728'},
        {'base':'U', 'letters':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
        {'base':'V', 'letters':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
        {'base':'VY','letters':'\uA760'},
        {'base':'W', 'letters':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
        {'base':'X', 'letters':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
        {'base':'Y', 'letters':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
        {'base':'Z', 'letters':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
        {'base':'a', 'letters':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'},
        {'base':'aa','letters':'\uA733'},
        {'base':'ae','letters':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
        {'base':'ao','letters':'\uA735'},
        {'base':'au','letters':'\uA737'},
        {'base':'av','letters':'\uA739\uA73B'},
        {'base':'ay','letters':'\uA73D'},
        {'base':'b', 'letters':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
        {'base':'c', 'letters':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'},
        {'base':'d', 'letters':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
        {'base':'dz','letters':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
        {'base':'e', 'letters':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
        {'base':'f', 'letters':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
        {'base':'g', 'letters':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
        {'base':'h', 'letters':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
        {'base':'hv','letters':'\u0195'},
        {'base':'i', 'letters':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'},
        {'base':'j', 'letters':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
        {'base':'k', 'letters':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
        {'base':'l', 'letters':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
        {'base':'lj','letters':'\u01C9'},
        {'base':'m', 'letters':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
        {'base':'n', 'letters':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
        {'base':'nj','letters':'\u01CC'},
        {'base':'o', 'letters':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'},
        {'base':'oi','letters':'\u01A3'},
        {'base':'ou','letters':'\u0223'},
        {'base':'oo','letters':'\uA74F'},
        {'base':'p','letters':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
        {'base':'q','letters':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
        {'base':'r','letters':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
        {'base':'s','letters':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
        {'base':'t','letters':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
        {'base':'tz','letters':'\uA729'},
        {'base':'u','letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'},
        {'base':'v','letters':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
        {'base':'vy','letters':'\uA761'},
        {'base':'w','letters':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
        {'base':'x','letters':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
        {'base':'y','letters':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
        {'base':'z','letters':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
    ];

    var diacriticsMap = {};
    for (var i=0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap .length; i++){
        var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap [i].letters;
        for (var j=0; j < letters.length ; j++){
            diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap [i].base;
        }
    }

    // "what?" version ... http://jsperf.com/diacritics/12
    function removeDiacritics (str) {
        return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function(a){ 
           return diacriticsMap[a] || a; 
        });
    }    
    var paragraph = "L'avantage d'utiliser le lorem ipsum est bien     évidemment de pouvoir créer des maquettes ou de remplir un site internet de contenus qui présentent un rendu s'approchant un maximum du rendu final. \n Par défaut lorem ipsum ne contient pas d'accent ni de caractères spéciaux contrairement à la langue française qui en contient beaucoup. C'est sur ce critère que nous proposons une solution avec cet outil qui générant du faux-texte lorem ipsum mais avec en plus, des caractères spéciaux tel que les accents ou certains symboles utiles pour la langue française. \n L'utilisation du lorem standard est facile d’utilisation mais lorsque le futur client utilisera votre logiciel il se peut que certains caractères spéciaux ou qu'un accent ne soient pas codés correctement. \n Cette page a pour but donc de pouvoir perdre le moins de temps possible et donc de tester directement si tous les encodages de base de donnée ou des sites sont les bons de plus il permet de récuperer un code css avec le texte formaté !";
    alert(removeDiacritics(paragraph));
```

To test my theory I wrote a test in http://jsperf.com/diacritics/12. Results:

Testing in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 32-bit on Windows 8 64-bit:
Using Regexp
4,558 ops/sec ±4.16%. 37% slower
String Builder style
7,308 ops/sec ±4.88%. fastest

### Update

Testing in Chrome 33.0.1750 on Windows 8 64-bit:

Using Regexp
5,260 ±1.25% ops/sec 76% slower
Using @skerit version
22,138 ±2.12% ops/sec fastest

#### Update - 19/03/2014

Adding missing "OE" diacritics.

#### Update - 27/03/2014

Using a faster way to transverse a string using js - "What?" Version

[image: jsPerf comparision]

#### Update - 14/05/2014

Community wiki

Comment: I added two more variations, but they aren't faster than the String Builder version (tested with Chrome and Firefox): http://jsperf.com/diacritics/3

Comment: I added another variation without using "in". Seriously: don't use "in", it's incredibly slow.

Comment: As @skerit has recommended, we should avoid use "in" operator to know if one key is present in Array. Looks like, JS engine has to transverse all array to know if the key is there.
I am really thinking put this answer as community version.

Comment: removeDiacritics('Rügen') -> 'Rügen'   :(

Comment: @DrakaSAN I could not help to try find out what is going on in the "What?" version, please have a look at http://jsbin.com/yewoyusevabe/1/edit?js,console enjoy :-)

Comment: @DrakaSAN here are very good resources I used to help me find out "what?" was going on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Very nice work, thank you. One question though: is the letters.split("") necessary? `letters.charAt(i)` and `letters.length` works fine in Chrome (I have not tested other browsers). Oh, and one minor tip: this is the only place you use double quotes, it broke the consistency warning in my JSHint. :)

Comment: @Chop  I am little bit insane about optimization. chatAt can be slower that direct accessing an array. http://jsperf.com/charat-or-array. But you are right  in both cases (including about consistency). But the answer is a community wiki. You are free to edit.

Comment: @rdllopes : Thanks for the answer. I am all for optimisation, and yes, your test proves that array access is faster than `charAt`. Yet the test you link fails to take the cost of the `split` operation into account. I tried to make it appear in a new version of the test (http://jsperf.com/charat-or-array/2), and `charAt` in this case is clearly faster. If my test (and my reasoning) is correct, this will give a chance for `split` + array access only for long strings, which these in the map are not. What do you think?

Comment: @chop your test is absolutely correct but is not "fair" in some cases (long strings for example), because we should split the array only once.  But, yes for small text, like this map splitting is too expensive. good catch.

Comment: @rdllopes It seemed more natural to me: you split the string and then browse the array once. I see it as part of the performance test. Yet I admit I am not familiar with jsperf and may have misunderstood how it calculates. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I am from Austria (Language German) and we have the letter ß that is usally without ligatures "ss". So I would make a seperate line for \u00DF like { 'base': 'ss', 'letters': '\u00DF' }. I modified the code for my Project but I think that's a general concern.

Comment: "Das is richtig" (that is true). But, now I realized that there is a problem here. ü in German should be ue. In portuguese, the same letter should be u, because there is no umlaut in that language. Trema was considered just an accent. @CodingYourLife

Comment: Thought about that too. I think it's not that big of a problem if Ü/Ä/Ö become u/a/o (maybe controversial). For example the last name Österreicher will become Osterreicher and that's understandable. The ß->s instead of ss is definitely a problem.

Comment: Considering that `'\u00DF'.toUpperCase()` evaluates to 'SS', I think converting `\u00DF` to ss is the right move. The post being a community wiki, perhaps @CodingYourLife would contribute the change you've made?

Comment: is 'defaultDiacriticsRemovalap' meant to be 'defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap'?

Comment: Is it just me or all these solutions are really complicated for no reason? I posted a simple solution below, anyone else care to see if it works for their use-case? Works fine for me.

Comment: @LewisDiamond, The definition of 'String.prototype.normalize' is part of  ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262) specification. This problem was asked Jun 13 2009.

Comment: I ended up adding `.replace(/[\u0301\u0060]/gi,'')` at the end to remove the blank space with accents. Sometimes in Mac OS, è can be e`

Comment: I wonder if there's any update on this, or of this was added to a currently maintained github repo, or something we we can track/add to it rather than on a stackoverflow wiki. I was about to create something but I found https://github.com/jprichardson/string.js which seems to include a latinise, it's likely not the same implementation but seems a good place to start, any other recommendations. Shall we create some small library out of this?

Comment: I just looked at the linked jsperf benchmarks, everyone is ignoring the fact that on many of the units, part of the code that needs to be perf'd is in the "setup" box, namely looping over the character map to build the object necessary for replacements. That's not setup code, it should be copied into each benchmark that uses it, and it's slow as heck.

Comment: @jonschlinkert i think that loop you see there, is just to build a "different" array map. But runs only once. Then you access that array.

Comment: A few changes I would suggest: Add:
    `ʏ` -> `Ue`,
    `ð` -> `d`,

Change:
    `ä` -> `ae`,
    `ö` -> `oe`,
    `ü` -> `ue`,
    `Ä` -> `Ae`,
    `Ö` -> `Oe`,
    `Ü` -> `Ue`,

    `å` -> `aa`,
    `Å` -> `Aa`,
    `ß` -> `ss`,
    `ẞ` -> `SS`,

Comment: Also `ĳ` -> `ij` and `Ĳ` -> `IJ`.

Comment: TypeScript version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-stackoverflow-diacritics?file=index.ts

Comment: why do you iterate over the map to make a new map?I think it makes more sense to hardcode the second map like done in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53957849/4088205

Comment: This combined with the accepted answer removed ALL but 
þ = th
Þ = Th
ⁿ = n
º = o
ð = d
for me. WHICH IS BRILLIANT

Comment: Another correction: ſ (U+017F, Latin Small Letter Long S) should be mapped to 's' instead of 'l'.

Answer (score 114):

A more complete version with case sensitive support, ligatures and whatnot.
Original source at: [http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918093154/http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/)

```
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
    {'base':'A', 'letters':/[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]/g},
    {'base':'AA','letters':/[\uA732]/g},
    {'base':'AE','letters':/[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]/g},
    {'base':'AO','letters':/[\uA734]/g},
    {'base':'AU','letters':/[\uA736]/g},
    {'base':'AV','letters':/[\uA738\uA73A]/g},
    {'base':'AY','letters':/[\uA73C]/g},
    {'base':'B', 'letters':/[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]/g},
    {'base':'C', 'letters':/[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]/g},
    {'base':'D', 'letters':/[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]/g},
    {'base':'DZ','letters':/[\u01F1\u01C4]/g},
    {'base':'Dz','letters':/[\u01F2\u01C5]/g},
    {'base':'E', 'letters':/[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]/g},
    {'base':'F', 'letters':/[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]/g},
    {'base':'G', 'letters':/[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]/g},
    {'base':'H', 'letters':/[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]/g},
    {'base':'I', 'letters':/[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]/g},
    {'base':'J', 'letters':/[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]/g},
    {'base':'K', 'letters':/[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]/g},
    {'base':'L', 'letters':/[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]/g},
    {'base':'LJ','letters':/[\u01C7]/g},
    {'base':'Lj','letters':/[\u01C8]/g},
    {'base':'M', 'letters':/[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]/g},
    {'base':'N', 'letters':/[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]/g},
    {'base':'NJ','letters':/[\u01CA]/g},
    {'base':'Nj','letters':/[\u01CB]/g},
    {'base':'O', 'letters':/[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]/g},
    {'base':'OI','letters':/[\u01A2]/g},
    {'base':'OO','letters':/[\uA74E]/g},
    {'base':'OU','letters':/[\u0222]/g},
    {'base':'P', 'letters':/[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]/g},
    {'base':'Q', 'letters':/[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]/g},
    {'base':'R', 'letters':/[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]/g},
    {'base':'S', 'letters':/[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]/g},
    {'base':'T', 'letters':/[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]/g},
    {'base':'TZ','letters':/[\uA728]/g},
    {'base':'U', 'letters':/[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]/g},
    {'base':'V', 'letters':/[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]/g},
    {'base':'VY','letters':/[\uA760]/g},
    {'base':'W', 'letters':/[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]/g},
    {'base':'X', 'letters':/[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]/g},
    {'base':'Y', 'letters':/[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]/g},
    {'base':'Z', 'letters':/[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]/g},
    {'base':'a', 'letters':/[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g},
    {'base':'aa','letters':/[\uA733]/g},
    {'base':'ae','letters':/[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3]/g},
    {'base':'ao','letters':/[\uA735]/g},
    {'base':'au','letters':/[\uA737]/g},
    {'base':'av','letters':/[\uA739\uA73B]/g},
    {'base':'ay','letters':/[\uA73D]/g},
    {'base':'b', 'letters':/[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]/g},
    {'base':'c', 'letters':/[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]/g},
    {'base':'d', 'letters':/[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]/g},
    {'base':'dz','letters':/[\u01F3\u01C6]/g},
    {'base':'e', 'letters':/[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g},
    {'base':'f', 'letters':/[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]/g},
    {'base':'g', 'letters':/[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]/g},
    {'base':'h', 'letters':/[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]/g},
    {'base':'hv','letters':/[\u0195]/g},
    {'base':'i', 'letters':/[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g},
    {'base':'j', 'letters':/[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]/g},
    {'base':'k', 'letters':/[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]/g},
    {'base':'l', 'letters':/[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]/g},
    {'base':'lj','letters':/[\u01C9]/g},
    {'base':'m', 'letters':/[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]/g},
    {'base':'n', 'letters':/[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]/g},
    {'base':'nj','letters':/[\u01CC]/g},
    {'base':'o', 'letters':/[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]/g},
    {'base':'oi','letters':/[\u01A3]/g},
    {'base':'ou','letters':/[\u0223]/g},
    {'base':'oo','letters':/[\uA74F]/g},
    {'base':'p','letters':/[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]/g},
    {'base':'q','letters':/[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]/g},
    {'base':'r','letters':/[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]/g},
    {'base':'s','letters':/[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]/g},
    {'base':'t','letters':/[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]/g},
    {'base':'tz','letters':/[\uA729]/g},
    {'base':'u','letters':/[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g},
    {'base':'v','letters':/[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]/g},
    {'base':'vy','letters':/[\uA761]/g},
    {'base':'w','letters':/[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]/g},
    {'base':'x','letters':/[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]/g},
    {'base':'y','letters':/[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]/g},
    {'base':'z','letters':/[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g}
];
var changes;
function removeDiacritics (str) {
    if(!changes) {
        changes = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<changes.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(changes[i].letters, changes[i].base);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain me why there is a "changes" var used there. Couldn't we simply use directly the diacriticsMap?

Comment: Yes you could. However, this allows you to substitute for another diacritics map by setting the value of `changes` to it.

Comment: At least make it an optional parameter of removeDiacritics, then. Jeez, really? An external variable? Why?

Comment: œ (`{ base: "oe", letters: /[\u0153]/g }`) and Œ (`{ base: "OE", letters: /[\u0152]/g }`) are missing.  Maybe there's more but since the OP mentioned these, I think they should be added.

Comment: A few changes I suggested to the modified version, will add it here as well: Missing:
    `ʏ` -> `Ue`,
    `ð` -> `d`,

Change:
    `ä` -> `ae`,
    `ö` -> `oe`,
    `ü` -> `ue`,
    `Ä` -> `Ae`,
    `Ö` -> `Oe`,
    `Ü` -> `Ue`,

    `å` -> `aa`,
    `Å` -> `Aa`,
    `ß` -> `ss`,
    `ẞ` -> `SS`,

Comment: Also `ĳ` -> `ij` and `Ĳ` -> `IJ`.

Comment: Not cool, the license. :-(

Answer (score 70):

Here is a very fast script based on the Unicode standard, taken from here:
http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript

```
var Latinise={};Latinise.latin_map={"Á":"A","Ă":"A","Ắ":"A","Ặ":"A","Ằ":"A","Ẳ":"A","Ẵ":"A","Ǎ":"A","Â":"A","Ấ":"A","Ậ":"A","Ầ":"A","Ẩ":"A","Ẫ":"A","Ä":"A","Ǟ":"A","Ȧ":"A","Ǡ":"A","Ạ":"A","Ȁ":"A","À":"A","Ả":"A","Ȃ":"A","Ā":"A","Ą":"A","Å":"A","Ǻ":"A","Ḁ":"A","Ⱥ":"A","Ã":"A","Ꜳ":"AA","Æ":"AE","Ǽ":"AE","Ǣ":"AE","Ꜵ":"AO","Ꜷ":"AU","Ꜹ":"AV","Ꜻ":"AV","Ꜽ":"AY","Ḃ":"B","Ḅ":"B","Ɓ":"B","Ḇ":"B","Ƀ":"B","Ƃ":"B","Ć":"C","Č":"C","Ç":"C","Ḉ":"C","Ĉ":"C","Ċ":"C","Ƈ":"C","Ȼ":"C","Ď":"D","Ḑ":"D","Ḓ":"D","Ḋ":"D","Ḍ":"D","Ɗ":"D","Ḏ":"D","ǲ":"D","ǅ":"D","Đ":"D","Ƌ":"D","Ǳ":"DZ","Ǆ":"DZ","É":"E","Ĕ":"E","Ě":"E","Ȩ":"E","Ḝ":"E","Ê":"E","Ế":"E","Ệ":"E","Ề":"E","Ể":"E","Ễ":"E","Ḙ":"E","Ë":"E","Ė":"E","Ẹ":"E","Ȅ":"E","È":"E","Ẻ":"E","Ȇ":"E","Ē":"E","Ḗ":"E","Ḕ":"E","Ę":"E","Ɇ":"E","Ẽ":"E","Ḛ":"E","Ꝫ":"ET","Ḟ":"F","Ƒ":"F","Ǵ":"G","Ğ":"G","Ǧ":"G","Ģ":"G","Ĝ":"G","Ġ":"G","Ɠ":"G","Ḡ":"G","Ǥ":"G","Ḫ":"H","Ȟ":"H","Ḩ":"H","Ĥ":"H","Ⱨ":"H","Ḧ":"H","Ḣ":"H","Ḥ":"H","Ħ":"H","Í":"I","Ĭ":"I","Ǐ":"I","Î":"I","Ï":"I","Ḯ":"I","İ":"I","Ị":"I","Ȉ":"I","Ì":"I","Ỉ":"I","Ȋ":"I","Ī":"I","Į":"I","Ɨ":"I","Ĩ":"I","Ḭ":"I","Ꝺ":"D","Ꝼ":"F","Ᵹ":"G","Ꞃ":"R","Ꞅ":"S","Ꞇ":"T","Ꝭ":"IS","Ĵ":"J","Ɉ":"J","Ḱ":"K","Ǩ":"K","Ķ":"K","Ⱪ":"K","Ꝃ":"K","Ḳ":"K","Ƙ":"K","Ḵ":"K","Ꝁ":"K","Ꝅ":"K","Ĺ":"L","Ƚ":"L","Ľ":"L","Ļ":"L","Ḽ":"L","Ḷ":"L","Ḹ":"L","Ⱡ":"L","Ꝉ":"L","Ḻ":"L","Ŀ":"L","Ɫ":"L","ǈ":"L","Ł":"L","Ǉ":"LJ","Ḿ":"M","Ṁ":"M","Ṃ":"M","Ɱ":"M","Ń":"N","Ň":"N","Ņ":"N","Ṋ":"N","Ṅ":"N","Ṇ":"N","Ǹ":"N","Ɲ":"N","Ṉ":"N","Ƞ":"N","ǋ":"N","Ñ":"N","Ǌ":"NJ","Ó":"O","Ŏ":"O","Ǒ":"O","Ô":"O","Ố":"O","Ộ":"O","Ồ":"O","Ổ":"O","Ỗ":"O","Ö":"O","Ȫ":"O","Ȯ":"O","Ȱ":"O","Ọ":"O","Ő":"O","Ȍ":"O","Ò":"O","Ỏ":"O","Ơ":"O","Ớ":"O","Ợ":"O","Ờ":"O","Ở":"O","Ỡ":"O","Ȏ":"O","Ꝋ":"O","Ꝍ":"O","Ō":"O","Ṓ":"O","Ṑ":"O","Ɵ":"O","Ǫ":"O","Ǭ":"O","Ø":"O","Ǿ":"O","Õ":"O","Ṍ":"O","Ṏ":"O","Ȭ":"O","Ƣ":"OI","Ꝏ":"OO","Ɛ":"E","Ɔ":"O","Ȣ":"OU","Ṕ":"P","Ṗ":"P","Ꝓ":"P","Ƥ":"P","Ꝕ":"P","Ᵽ":"P","Ꝑ":"P","Ꝙ":"Q","Ꝗ":"Q","Ŕ":"R","Ř":"R","Ŗ":"R","Ṙ":"R","Ṛ":"R","Ṝ":"R","Ȑ":"R","Ȓ":"R","Ṟ":"R","Ɍ":"R","Ɽ":"R","Ꜿ":"C","Ǝ":"E","Ś":"S","Ṥ":"S","Š":"S","Ṧ":"S","Ş":"S","Ŝ":"S","Ș":"S","Ṡ":"S","Ṣ":"S","Ṩ":"S","Ť":"T","Ţ":"T","Ṱ":"T","Ț":"T","Ⱦ":"T","Ṫ":"T","Ṭ":"T","Ƭ":"T","Ṯ":"T","Ʈ":"T","Ŧ":"T","Ɐ":"A","Ꞁ":"L","Ɯ":"M","Ʌ":"V","Ꜩ":"TZ","Ú":"U","Ŭ":"U","Ǔ":"U","Û":"U","Ṷ":"U","Ü":"U","Ǘ":"U","Ǚ":"U","Ǜ":"U","Ǖ":"U","Ṳ":"U","Ụ":"U","Ű":"U","Ȕ":"U","Ù":"U","Ủ":"U","Ư":"U","Ứ":"U","Ự":"U","Ừ":"U","Ử":"U","Ữ":"U","Ȗ":"U","Ū":"U","Ṻ":"U","Ų":"U","Ů":"U","Ũ":"U","Ṹ":"U","Ṵ":"U","Ꝟ":"V","Ṿ":"V","Ʋ":"V","Ṽ":"V","Ꝡ":"VY","Ẃ":"W","Ŵ":"W","Ẅ":"W","Ẇ":"W","Ẉ":"W","Ẁ":"W","Ⱳ":"W","Ẍ":"X","Ẋ":"X","Ý":"Y","Ŷ":"Y","Ÿ":"Y","Ẏ":"Y","Ỵ":"Y","Ỳ":"Y","Ƴ":"Y","Ỷ":"Y","Ỿ":"Y","Ȳ":"Y","Ɏ":"Y","Ỹ":"Y","Ź":"Z","Ž":"Z","Ẑ":"Z","Ⱬ":"Z","Ż":"Z","Ẓ":"Z","Ȥ":"Z","Ẕ":"Z","Ƶ":"Z","Ĳ":"IJ","Œ":"OE","ᴀ":"A","ᴁ":"AE","ʙ":"B","ᴃ":"B","ᴄ":"C","ᴅ":"D","ᴇ":"E","ꜰ":"F","ɢ":"G","ʛ":"G","ʜ":"H","ɪ":"I","ʁ":"R","ᴊ":"J","ᴋ":"K","ʟ":"L","ᴌ":"L","ᴍ":"M","ɴ":"N","ᴏ":"O","ɶ":"OE","ᴐ":"O","ᴕ":"OU","ᴘ":"P","ʀ":"R","ᴎ":"N","ᴙ":"R","ꜱ":"S","ᴛ":"T","ⱻ":"E","ᴚ":"R","ᴜ":"U","ᴠ":"V","ᴡ":"W","ʏ":"Y","ᴢ":"Z","á":"a","ă":"a","ắ":"a","ặ":"a","ằ":"a","ẳ":"a","ẵ":"a","ǎ":"a","â":"a","ấ":"a","ậ":"a","ầ":"a","ẩ":"a","ẫ":"a","ä":"a","ǟ":"a","ȧ":"a","ǡ":"a","ạ":"a","ȁ":"a","à":"a","ả":"a","ȃ":"a","ā":"a","ą":"a","ᶏ":"a","ẚ":"a","å":"a","ǻ":"a","ḁ":"a","ⱥ":"a","ã":"a","ꜳ":"aa","æ":"ae","ǽ":"ae","ǣ":"ae","ꜵ":"ao","ꜷ":"au","ꜹ":"av","ꜻ":"av","ꜽ":"ay","ḃ":"b","ḅ":"b","ɓ":"b","ḇ":"b","ᵬ":"b","ᶀ":"b","ƀ":"b","ƃ":"b","ɵ":"o","ć":"c","č":"c","ç":"c","ḉ":"c","ĉ":"c","ɕ":"c","ċ":"c","ƈ":"c","ȼ":"c","ď":"d","ḑ":"d","ḓ":"d","ȡ":"d","ḋ":"d","ḍ":"d","ɗ":"d","ᶑ":"d","ḏ":"d","ᵭ":"d","ᶁ":"d","đ":"d","ɖ":"d","ƌ":"d","ı":"i","ȷ":"j","ɟ":"j","ʄ":"j","ǳ":"dz","ǆ":"dz","é":"e","ĕ":"e","ě":"e","ȩ":"e","ḝ":"e","ê":"e","ế":"e","ệ":"e","ề":"e","ể":"e","ễ":"e","ḙ":"e","ë":"e","ė":"e","ẹ":"e","ȅ":"e","è":"e","ẻ":"e","ȇ":"e","ē":"e","ḗ":"e","ḕ":"e","ⱸ":"e","ę":"e","ᶒ":"e","ɇ":"e","ẽ":"e","ḛ":"e","ꝫ":"et","ḟ":"f","ƒ":"f","ᵮ":"f","ᶂ":"f","ǵ":"g","ğ":"g","ǧ":"g","ģ":"g","ĝ":"g","ġ":"g","ɠ":"g","ḡ":"g","ᶃ":"g","ǥ":"g","ḫ":"h","ȟ":"h","ḩ":"h","ĥ":"h","ⱨ":"h","ḧ":"h","ḣ":"h","ḥ":"h","ɦ":"h","ẖ":"h","ħ":"h","ƕ":"hv","í":"i","ĭ":"i","ǐ":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ḯ":"i","ị":"i","ȉ":"i","ì":"i","ỉ":"i","ȋ":"i","ī":"i","į":"i","ᶖ":"i","ɨ":"i","ĩ":"i","ḭ":"i","ꝺ":"d","ꝼ":"f","ᵹ":"g","ꞃ":"r","ꞅ":"s","ꞇ":"t","ꝭ":"is","ǰ":"j","ĵ":"j","ʝ":"j","ɉ":"j","ḱ":"k","ǩ":"k","ķ":"k","ⱪ":"k","ꝃ":"k","ḳ":"k","ƙ":"k","ḵ":"k","ᶄ":"k","ꝁ":"k","ꝅ":"k","ĺ":"l","ƚ":"l","ɬ":"l","ľ":"l","ļ":"l","ḽ":"l","ȴ":"l","ḷ":"l","ḹ":"l","ⱡ":"l","ꝉ":"l","ḻ":"l","ŀ":"l","ɫ":"l","ᶅ":"l","ɭ":"l","ł":"l","ǉ":"lj","ſ":"s","ẜ":"s","ẛ":"s","ẝ":"s","ḿ":"m","ṁ":"m","ṃ":"m","ɱ":"m","ᵯ":"m","ᶆ":"m","ń":"n","ň":"n","ņ":"n","ṋ":"n","ȵ":"n","ṅ":"n","ṇ":"n","ǹ":"n","ɲ":"n","ṉ":"n","ƞ":"n","ᵰ":"n","ᶇ":"n","ɳ":"n","ñ":"n","ǌ":"nj","ó":"o","ŏ":"o","ǒ":"o","ô":"o","ố":"o","ộ":"o","ồ":"o","ổ":"o","ỗ":"o","ö":"o","ȫ":"o","ȯ":"o","ȱ":"o","ọ":"o","ő":"o","ȍ":"o","ò":"o","ỏ":"o","ơ":"o","ớ":"o","ợ":"o","ờ":"o","ở":"o","ỡ":"o","ȏ":"o","ꝋ":"o","ꝍ":"o","ⱺ":"o","ō":"o","ṓ":"o","ṑ":"o","ǫ":"o","ǭ":"o","ø":"o","ǿ":"o","õ":"o","ṍ":"o","ṏ":"o","ȭ":"o","ƣ":"oi","ꝏ":"oo","ɛ":"e","ᶓ":"e","ɔ":"o","ᶗ":"o","ȣ":"ou","ṕ":"p","ṗ":"p","ꝓ":"p","ƥ":"p","ᵱ":"p","ᶈ":"p","ꝕ":"p","ᵽ":"p","ꝑ":"p","ꝙ":"q","ʠ":"q","ɋ":"q","ꝗ":"q","ŕ":"r","ř":"r","ŗ":"r","ṙ":"r","ṛ":"r","ṝ":"r","ȑ":"r","ɾ":"r","ᵳ":"r","ȓ":"r","ṟ":"r","ɼ":"r","ᵲ":"r","ᶉ":"r","ɍ":"r","ɽ":"r","ↄ":"c","ꜿ":"c","ɘ":"e","ɿ":"r","ś":"s","ṥ":"s","š":"s","ṧ":"s","ş":"s","ŝ":"s","ș":"s","ṡ":"s","ṣ":"s","ṩ":"s","ʂ":"s","ᵴ":"s","ᶊ":"s","ȿ":"s","ɡ":"g","ᴑ":"o","ᴓ":"o","ᴝ":"u","ť":"t","ţ":"t","ṱ":"t","ț":"t","ȶ":"t","ẗ":"t","ⱦ":"t","ṫ":"t","ṭ":"t","ƭ":"t","ṯ":"t","ᵵ":"t","ƫ":"t","ʈ":"t","ŧ":"t","ᵺ":"th","ɐ":"a","ᴂ":"ae","ǝ":"e","ᵷ":"g","ɥ":"h","ʮ":"h","ʯ":"h","ᴉ":"i","ʞ":"k","ꞁ":"l","ɯ":"m","ɰ":"m","ᴔ":"oe","ɹ":"r","ɻ":"r","ɺ":"r","ⱹ":"r","ʇ":"t","ʌ":"v","ʍ":"w","ʎ":"y","ꜩ":"tz","ú":"u","ŭ":"u","ǔ":"u","û":"u","ṷ":"u","ü":"u","ǘ":"u","ǚ":"u","ǜ":"u","ǖ":"u","ṳ":"u","ụ":"u","ű":"u","ȕ":"u","ù":"u","ủ":"u","ư":"u","ứ":"u","ự":"u","ừ":"u","ử":"u","ữ":"u","ȗ":"u","ū":"u","ṻ":"u","ų":"u","ᶙ":"u","ů":"u","ũ":"u","ṹ":"u","ṵ":"u","ᵫ":"ue","ꝸ":"um","ⱴ":"v","ꝟ":"v","ṿ":"v","ʋ":"v","ᶌ":"v","ⱱ":"v","ṽ":"v","ꝡ":"vy","ẃ":"w","ŵ":"w","ẅ":"w","ẇ":"w","ẉ":"w","ẁ":"w","ⱳ":"w","ẘ":"w","ẍ":"x","ẋ":"x","ᶍ":"x","ý":"y","ŷ":"y","ÿ":"y","ẏ":"y","ỵ":"y","ỳ":"y","ƴ":"y","ỷ":"y","ỿ":"y","ȳ":"y","ẙ":"y","ɏ":"y","ỹ":"y","ź":"z","ž":"z","ẑ":"z","ʑ":"z","ⱬ":"z","ż":"z","ẓ":"z","ȥ":"z","ẕ":"z","ᵶ":"z","ᶎ":"z","ʐ":"z","ƶ":"z","ɀ":"z","ﬀ":"ff","ﬃ":"ffi","ﬄ":"ffl","ﬁ":"fi","ﬂ":"fl","ĳ":"ij","œ":"oe","ﬆ":"st","ₐ":"a","ₑ":"e","ᵢ":"i","ⱼ":"j","ₒ":"o","ᵣ":"r","ᵤ":"u","ᵥ":"v","ₓ":"x"};
String.prototype.latinise=function(){return this.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\[\] ]/g,function(a){return Latinise.latin_map[a]||a})};
String.prototype.latinize=String.prototype.latinise;
String.prototype.isLatin=function(){return this==this.latinise()}
```

Some examples:

```
> "Piqué".latinize();
"Pique"
> "Piqué".isLatin();
false
> "Pique".isLatin();
true
> "Piqué".latinise().isLatin();
true
```

To ensure the above latin_map doesn't get corrupted by copy/pasting or other transformations, use this base64 encoded string, replacing the first line of the above:

```
var base64map="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";
var Latinise={};Latinise.latin_map=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(base64map))));
```

Comment: This requires utf8 for the file encoding. For me this is a bit tricky, so I'm converting the characters do their unicode escape sequences. Ex. ç -> \u00E7

Comment: It's really slow

Answer (score 70):

You can use the [`_.deburr()`](https://lodash.com/docs#deburr) method from the Lodash library.

It's available as a stand-alone NPM package [`lodash.deburr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.deburr), or as part of the [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) package.

```
const myStringWithAccent = 'Mon café est plein de caféïne';
const myStringWithoutAccent = _.deburr( myStringWithAccent, );
```

The result will be : `"Mon cafe est plein de cafeine"`

Comment: works fine with diacritics and ligatures too. could be use in _flow_ with other lodash functions like trim, kebabCase to have canonical name : `var canonical_name = _.flow([_.trim, _.deburr, _.lowerCase]);`

Comment: This answer made my day, I've been searching for ever for some good code for that since I cannot use normalize("NFD") due to old safari browser support.

Comment: `_.deburr` does not work with all Vietnamese characters, for example, "Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh" would be "Thanh phố Hồ Chi Minh".

Comment: @phucbm It works fine if you use `.normalize('NFKD')`

Answer (score 49):

The format for new RegExp is

```
RegExp(something, 'modifiers');
```

So you would want

```
accentsTidy = function(s){
                        var r=s.toLowerCase();
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'),"");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'),"a");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'),"ae");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'),"c");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'),"e");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'),"i");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("ñ", 'g'),"n");                            
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'),"o");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'),"oe");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'),"u");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'),"y");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\W", 'g'),"");
                        return r;
                };
```

Comment: +1 for Ian. @subtenante see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Couldn't get this code to work. Make sure to set the doc encoding to UTF8!

Comment: Excellent solution, just a tiny note: add these two chars to their proper positions: `ő`, `ű`

Comment: Excellent solution! One can shorten this further by encapsulating all non ascii chrs in an associative array and iterating over it. I'll post that as an alternative answer below, because comments don't work for it. Thanks!

Comment: you can add `ğ` `ş` and `ı` for Turkish letters. Add `ı` in the list of `i`

Answer (score 18):

In NPM there is a package for this: [latinize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latinize)

It's a very good package to solve this issue.

Answer (score 16):

Shortened code based on the excellent solution by Ian Elliott:

```
accentsTidy = function(s){
    var r = s.toLowerCase();
    non_asciis = {'a': '[àáâãäå]', 'ae': 'æ', 'c': 'ç', 'e': '[èéêë]', 'i': '[ìíîï]', 'n': 'ñ', 'o': '[òóôõö]', 'oe': 'œ', 'u': '[ùúûűü]', 'y': '[ýÿ]'};
    for (i in non_asciis) { r = r.replace(new RegExp(non_asciis[i], 'g'), i); }
    return r;
};
```

Edit: Corrected non-working code

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is VERY slow. I tested it with a large unordered list and the performance hit is big, compared to other methods explained in this page (I've ended using the accepted answer). BTW, I've corrected a bug in your code. You had a call to a non-existing variable named "url" in the fourth line.

Answer (score 14):

There's a lot out there, but I think this one is simple and good enough:

```
 function remove_accents(strAccents) {
    var strAccents = strAccents.split('');
    var strAccentsOut = new Array();
    var strAccentsLen = strAccents.length;
    var accents =    "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçðÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž";
    var accentsOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeCcdDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz";
    for (var y = 0; y < strAccentsLen; y++) {
        if (accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]) != -1) {
            strAccentsOut[y] = accentsOut.substr(accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]), 1);
        } else
            strAccentsOut[y] = strAccents[y];
    }
    strAccentsOut = strAccentsOut.join('');

    return strAccentsOut;
}
```

If you also want to remove special characters and transform spaces and hyphens in underscores, do this:

```
string = remove_accents(string);
string = string.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[-\s]/g, '_');
```

Comment: I think `ð` (which uppercase is `Ð`) should be replaced by `d`
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth

Comment: @ekqnp updated `ð` => `d`, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

One solution that seems to be way faster by the given test : http://jsperf.com/diacritics/9

```
function removeDiacritics(str) {
   return str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+/g, function(a){
      return diacriticsMap[a] || a; 
   });
}
removeDiacritics(teste);
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/sovorute/1/edit

*Reasoning*: One reason this is much faster is because we only iterate through the special characters, picked by the negated regex pattern. The fastest of the tests (*String Iteration without in*) iterates 1001 on the given text, which means *every character*. This one iterates only 35 times and outputs the *same result*. Keep in mind that this will only replace what is indicated in the map.

Classic article on the subject: http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete

*Credit*: http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript , also provides a nice character map.

Comment: uhm, should that + be there?

Answer (score 7):

A simpler way to replace the diacriticals.

```
function replaceDiacritics(str){

  var diacritics = [
    {char: 'A', base: /[\300-\306]/g},
    {char: 'a', base: /[\340-\346]/g},
    {char: 'E', base: /[\310-\313]/g},
    {char: 'e', base: /[\350-\353]/g},
    {char: 'I', base: /[\314-\317]/g},
    {char: 'i', base: /[\354-\357]/g},
    {char: 'O', base: /[\322-\330]/g},
    {char: 'o', base: /[\362-\370]/g},
    {char: 'U', base: /[\331-\334]/g},
    {char: 'u', base: /[\371-\374]/g},
    {char: 'N', base: /[\321]/g},
    {char: 'n', base: /[\361]/g},
    {char: 'C', base: /[\307]/g},
    {char: 'c', base: /[\347]/g}
  ]

  diacritics.forEach(function(letter){
    str = str.replace(letter.base, letter.char);
  });

  return str;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Example for "Forța uriașă"

Answer (score 5):

I use GitHub Jakub Dundalek's repository [Latinize.js](https://github.com/dundalek/latinize).

```js
var latinize = require('latinize');
latinize('ỆᶍǍᶆṔƚÉ áéíóúýčďěňřšťžů'); // => 'ExAmPlE aeiouycdenrstzu'
```

Answer (score 4):

I have forked [billy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384701/billy)'s code 
http://jsfiddle.net/billybraga/UHmnf/ (from his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13475120/2426309)) into this: http://jsfiddle.net/infralabs/dJX58/

I corrected transcription of *ſ* and *ß* characters and also added coversion of these ones: *Þþ*, *Ðð*, *Ŋŋ*, *Ĳĳ*, *Œœ*.

The modified snippet is below:

```
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [{
    'base': "A",
        'letters': /(&#65;|&#9398;|&#65313;|&#192;|&#193;|&#194;|&#7846;|&#7844;|&#7850;|&#7848;|&#195;|&#256;|&#258;|&#7856;|&#7854;|&#7860;|&#7858;|&#550;|&#480;|&#196;|&#478;|&#7842;|&#197;|&#506;|&#461;|&#512;|&#514;|&#7840;|&#7852;|&#7862;|&#7680;|&#260;|&#570;|&#11375;|[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F])/g
}, {
    'base': "AA",
        'letters': /(&#42802;|[\uA732])/g
}, {
    'base': "AE",
        'letters': /(&#198;|&#508;|&#482;|[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2])/g
}, {
    'base': "AO",
        'letters': /(&#42804;|[\uA734])/g
}, {
    'base': "AU",
        'letters': /(&#42806;|[\uA736])/g
}, {
    'base': "AV",
        'letters': /(&#42808;|&#42810;|[\uA738\uA73A])/g
}, {
    'base': "AY",
        'letters': /(&#42812;|[\uA73C])/g
}, {
    'base': "B",
        'letters': /(&#66;|&#9399;|&#65314;|&#7682;|&#7684;|&#7686;|&#579;|&#386;|&#385;|[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181])/g
}, {
    'base': "C",
        'letters': /(&#67;|&#9400;|&#65315;|&#262;|&#264;|&#266;|&#268;|&#199;|&#7688;|&#391;|&#571;|&#42814;|[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E])/g
}, {
    'base': "D",
        'letters': /(&#68;|&#9401;|&#65316;|&#7690;|&#270;|&#7692;|&#7696;|&#7698;|&#7694;|&#272;|&#395;|&#394;|&#393;|&#42873;|&#208;|[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0])/g
}, {
    'base': "DZ",
        'letters': /(&#497;|&#452;|[\u01F1\u01C4])/g
}, {
    'base': "Dz",
        'letters': /(&#498;|&#453;|[\u01F2\u01C5])/g
}, {
    'base': "E",
        'letters': /(&#69;|&#9402;|&#65317;|&#200;|&#201;|&#202;|&#7872;|&#7870;|&#7876;|&#7874;|&#7868;|&#274;|&#7700;|&#7702;|&#276;|&#278;|&#203;|&#7866;|&#282;|&#516;|&#518;|&#7864;|&#7878;|&#552;|&#7708;|&#280;|&#7704;|&#7706;|&#400;|&#398;|[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E])/g
}, {
    'base': "F",
        'letters': /(&#70;|&#9403;|&#65318;|&#7710;|&#401;|&#42875;|[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B])/g
}, {
    'base': "G",
        'letters': /(&#71;|&#9404;|&#65319;|&#500;|&#284;|&#7712;|&#286;|&#288;|&#486;|&#290;|&#484;|&#403;|&#42912;|&#42877;|&#42878;|[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E])/g
}, {
    'base': "H",
        'letters': /(&#72;|&#9405;|&#65320;|&#292;|&#7714;|&#7718;|&#542;|&#7716;|&#7720;|&#7722;|&#294;|&#11367;|&#11381;|&#42893;|[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D])/g
}, {
    'base': "I",
        'letters': /(&#73;|&#9406;|&#65321;|&#204;|&#205;|&#206;|&#296;|&#298;|&#300;|&#304;|&#207;|&#7726;|&#7880;|&#463;|&#520;|&#522;|&#7882;|&#302;|&#7724;|&#407;|[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197])/g
}, {
    'base': "J",
        'letters': /(&#74;|&#9407;|&#65322;|&#308;|&#584;|[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248])/g
}, {
    'base': "K",
        'letters': /(&#75;|&#9408;|&#65323;|&#7728;|&#488;|&#7730;|&#310;|&#7732;|&#408;|&#11369;|&#42816;|&#42818;|&#42820;|&#42914;|[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2])/g
}, {
    'base': "L",
        'letters': /(&#76;|&#9409;|&#65324;|&#319;|&#313;|&#317;|&#7734;|&#7736;|&#315;|&#7740;|&#7738;|&#321;|&#573;|&#11362;|&#11360;|&#42824;|&#42822;|&#42880;|[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780])/g
}, {
    'base': "LJ",
        'letters': /(&#455;|[\u01C7])/g
}, {
    'base': "Lj",
        'letters': /(&#456;|[\u01C8])/g
}, {
    'base': "M",
        'letters': /(&#77;|&#9410;|&#65325;|&#7742;|&#7744;|&#7746;|&#11374;|&#412;|[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C])/g
}, {
    'base': "N",
        'letters': /(&#78;|&#9411;|&#65326;|&#504;|&#323;|&#209;|&#7748;|&#327;|&#7750;|&#325;|&#7754;|&#7752;|&#544;|&#413;|&#42896;|&#42916;|&#330;|[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4\u014A])/g
}, {
    'base': "NJ",
        'letters': /(&#458;|[\u01CA])/g
}, {
    'base': "Nj",
        'letters': /(&#459;|[\u01CB])/g
}, {
    'base': "O",
        'letters': /(&#79;|&#9412;|&#65327;|&#210;|&#211;|&#212;|&#7890;|&#7888;|&#7894;|&#7892;|&#213;|&#7756;|&#556;|&#7758;|&#332;|&#7760;|&#7762;|&#334;|&#558;|&#560;|&#214;|&#554;|&#7886;|&#336;|&#465;|&#524;|&#526;|&#416;|&#7900;|&#7898;|&#7904;|&#7902;|&#7906;|&#7884;|&#7896;|&#490;|&#492;|&#216;|&#510;|&#390;|&#415;|&#42826;|&#42828;|[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C])/g
}, {
    'base': "OE",
        'letters': /(&#338;|[\u0152])/g
}, {
    'base': "OI",
        'letters': /(&#418;|[\u01A2])/g
}, {
    'base': "OO",
        'letters': /(&#42830;|[\uA74E])/g
}, {
    'base': "OU",
        'letters': /(&#546;|[\u0222])/g
}, {
    'base': "P",
        'letters': /(&#80;|&#9413;|&#65328;|&#7764;|&#7766;|&#420;|&#11363;|&#42832;|&#42834;|&#42836;|[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754])/g
}, {
    'base': "Q",
        'letters': /(&#81;|&#9414;|&#65329;|&#42838;|&#42840;|&#586;|[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A])/g
}, {
    'base': "R",
        'letters': /(&#82;|&#9415;|&#65330;|&#340;|&#7768;|&#344;|&#528;|&#530;|&#7770;|&#7772;|&#342;|&#7774;|&#588;|&#11364;|&#42842;|&#42918;|&#42882;|[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782])/g
}, {
    'base': "S",
        'letters': /(&#83;|&#9416;|&#65331;|&#7838;|&#346;|&#7780;|&#348;|&#7776;|&#352;|&#7782;|&#7778;|&#7784;|&#536;|&#350;|&#11390;|&#42920;|&#42884;|[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784])/g
}, {
    'base': "T",
        'letters': /(&#84;|&#9417;|&#65332;|&#7786;|&#356;|&#7788;|&#538;|&#354;|&#7792;|&#7790;|&#358;|&#428;|&#430;|&#574;|&#42886;|[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786])/g
}, {
    'base': "TH",
        'letters': /(&#222;|[\u00DE])/g
}, {
    'base': "TZ",
        'letters': /(&#42792;|[\uA728])/g
}, {
    'base': "U",
        'letters': /(&#85;|&#9418;|&#65333;|&#217;|&#218;|&#219;|&#360;|&#7800;|&#362;|&#7802;|&#364;|&#220;|&#475;|&#471;|&#469;|&#473;|&#7910;|&#366;|&#368;|&#467;|&#532;|&#534;|&#431;|&#7914;|&#7912;|&#7918;|&#7916;|&#7920;|&#7908;|&#7794;|&#370;|&#7798;|&#7796;|&#580;|[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244])/g
}, {
    'base': "V",
        'letters': /(&#86;|&#9419;|&#65334;|&#7804;|&#7806;|&#434;|&#42846;|&#581;|[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245])/g
}, {
    'base': "VY",
        'letters': /(&#42848;|[\uA760])/g
}, {
    'base': "W",
        'letters': /(&#87;|&#9420;|&#65335;|&#7808;|&#7810;|&#372;|&#7814;|&#7812;|&#7816;|&#11378;|[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72])/g
}, {
    'base': "X",
        'letters': /(&#88;|&#9421;|&#65336;|&#7818;|&#7820;|[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C])/g
}, {
    'base': "Y",
        'letters': /(&#89;|&#9422;|&#65337;|&#7922;|&#221;|&#374;|&#7928;|&#562;|&#7822;|&#376;|&#7926;|&#7924;|&#435;|&#590;|&#7934;|[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE])/g
}, {
    'base': "Z",
        'letters': /(&#90;|&#9423;|&#65338;|&#377;|&#7824;|&#379;|&#381;|&#7826;|&#7828;|&#437;|&#548;|&#11391;|&#11371;|&#42850;|[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762])/g
}, {
    'base': "a",
        'letters': /(&#97;|&#9424;|&#65345;|&#7834;|&#224;|&#225;|&#226;|&#7847;|&#7845;|&#7851;|&#7849;|&#227;|&#257;|&#259;|&#7857;|&#7855;|&#7861;|&#7859;|&#551;|&#481;|&#228;|&#479;|&#7843;|&#229;|&#507;|&#462;|&#513;|&#515;|&#7841;|&#7853;|&#7863;|&#7681;|&#261;|&#11365;|&#592;|[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250])/g
}, {
    'base': "aa",
        'letters': /(&#42803;|[\uA733])/g
}, {
    'base': "ae",
        'letters': /(&#230;|&#509;|&#483;|[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3])/g
}, {
    'base': "ao",
        'letters': /(&#42805;|[\uA735])/g
}, {
    'base': "au",
        'letters': /(&#42807;|[\uA737])/g
}, {
    'base': "av",
        'letters': /(&#42809;|&#42811;|[\uA739\uA73B])/g
}, {
    'base': "ay",
        'letters': /(&#42813;|[\uA73D])/g
}, {
    'base': "b",
        'letters': /(&#98;|&#9425;|&#65346;|&#7683;|&#7685;|&#7687;|&#384;|&#387;|&#595;|[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253])/g
}, {
    'base': "c",
        'letters': /(&#99;|&#9426;|&#65347;|&#263;|&#265;|&#267;|&#269;|&#231;|&#7689;|&#392;|&#572;|&#42815;|&#8580;|[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184])/g
}, {
    'base': "d",
        'letters': /(&#100;|&#9427;|&#65348;|&#7691;|&#271;|&#7693;|&#7697;|&#7699;|&#7695;|&#273;|&#396;|&#598;|&#599;|&#42874;|&#240;|[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A\u00F0])/g
}, {
    'base': "dz",
        'letters': /(&#499;|&#454;|[\u01F3\u01C6])/g
}, {
    'base': "e",
        'letters': /(&#101;|&#9428;|&#65349;|&#232;|&#233;|&#234;|&#7873;|&#7871;|&#7877;|&#7875;|&#7869;|&#275;|&#7701;|&#7703;|&#277;|&#279;|&#235;|&#7867;|&#283;|&#517;|&#519;|&#7865;|&#7879;|&#553;|&#7709;|&#281;|&#7705;|&#7707;|&#583;|&#603;|&#477;|[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD])/g
}, {
    'base': "f",
        'letters': /(&#102;|&#9429;|&#65350;|&#7711;|&#402;|&#42876;|[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C])/g
}, {
    'base': "g",
        'letters': /(&#103;|&#9430;|&#65351;|&#501;|&#285;|&#7713;|&#287;|&#289;|&#487;|&#291;|&#485;|&#608;|&#42913;|&#7545;|&#42879;|[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F])/g
}, {
    'base': "h",
        'letters': /(&#104;|&#9431;|&#65352;|&#293;|&#7715;|&#7719;|&#543;|&#7717;|&#7721;|&#7723;|&#7830;|&#295;|&#11368;|&#11382;|&#613;|[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265])/g
}, {
    'base': "hv",
        'letters': /(&#405;|[\u0195])/g
}, {
    'base': "i",
        'letters': /(&#105;|&#9432;|&#65353;|&#236;|&#237;|&#238;|&#297;|&#299;|&#301;|&#239;|&#7727;|&#7881;|&#464;|&#521;|&#523;|&#7883;|&#303;|&#7725;|&#616;|&#305;|[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131])/g
}, {
    'base': "ij",
        'letters': /(&#307;|[\u0133])/g
}, {
    'base': "j",
        'letters': /(&#106;|&#9433;|&#65354;|&#309;|&#496;|&#585;|[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249])/g
}, {
    'base': "k",
        'letters': /(&#107;|&#9434;|&#65355;|&#7729;|&#489;|&#7731;|&#311;|&#7733;|&#409;|&#11370;|&#42817;|&#42819;|&#42821;|&#42915;|[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3])/g
}, {
    'base': "l",
        'letters': /(&#108;|&#9435;|&#65356;|&#320;|&#314;|&#318;|&#7735;|&#7737;|&#316;|&#7741;|&#7739;|&#322;|&#410;|&#619;|&#11361;|&#42825;|&#42881;|&#42823;|[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747])/g
}, {
    'base': "lj",
        'letters': /(&#457;|[\u01C9])/g
}, {
    'base': "m",
        'letters': /(&#109;|&#9436;|&#65357;|&#7743;|&#7745;|&#7747;|&#625;|&#623;|[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F])/g
}, {
    'base': "n",
        'letters': /(&#110;|&#9437;|&#65358;|&#505;|&#324;|&#241;|&#7749;|&#328;|&#7751;|&#326;|&#7755;|&#7753;|&#414;|&#626;|&#329;|&#42897;|&#42917;|&#331;|[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5\u014B])/g
}, {
    'base': "nj",
        'letters': /(&#460;|[\u01CC])/g
}, {
    'base': "o",
        'letters': /(&#111;|&#9438;|&#65359;|&#242;|&#243;|&#244;|&#7891;|&#7889;|&#7895;|&#7893;|&#245;|&#7757;|&#557;|&#7759;|&#333;|&#7761;|&#7763;|&#335;|&#559;|&#561;|&#246;|&#555;|&#7887;|&#337;|&#466;|&#525;|&#527;|&#417;|&#7901;|&#7899;|&#7905;|&#7903;|&#7907;|&#7885;|&#7897;|&#491;|&#493;|&#248;|&#511;|&#596;|&#42827;|&#42829;|&#629;|[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275])/g
}, {
    'base': "oe",
        'letters': /(&#339;|[\u0153])/g
}, {
    'base': "oi",
        'letters': /(&#419;|[\u01A3])/g
}, {
    'base': "ou",
        'letters': /(&#547;|[\u0223])/g
}, {
    'base': "oo",
        'letters': /(&#42831;|[\uA74F])/g
}, {
    'base': "p",
        'letters': /(&#112;|&#9439;|&#65360;|&#7765;|&#7767;|&#421;|&#7549;|&#42833;|&#42835;|&#42837;|[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755])/g
}, {
    'base': "q",
        'letters': /(&#113;|&#9440;|&#65361;|&#587;|&#42839;|&#42841;|[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759])/g
}, {
    'base': "r",
        'letters': /(&#114;|&#9441;|&#65362;|&#341;|&#7769;|&#345;|&#529;|&#531;|&#7771;|&#7773;|&#343;|&#7775;|&#589;|&#637;|&#42843;|&#42919;|&#42883;|[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783])/g
}, {
    'base': "s",
        'letters': /(&#115;|&#9442;|&#65363;|&#347;|&#7781;|&#349;|&#7777;|&#353;|&#7783;|&#7779;|&#7785;|&#537;|&#351;|&#575;|&#42921;|&#42885;|&#7835;|&#383;|[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B\u017F])/g
}, {
    'base': "ss",
        'letters': /(&#223;|[\u00DF])/g
}, {
    'base': "t",
        'letters': /(&#116;|&#9443;|&#65364;|&#7787;|&#7831;|&#357;|&#7789;|&#539;|&#355;|&#7793;|&#7791;|&#359;|&#429;|&#648;|&#11366;|&#42887;|[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787])/g
}, {
    'base': "th",
        'letters': /(&#254;|[\u00FE])/g
}, {
    'base': "tz",
        'letters': /(&#42793;|[\uA729])/g
}, {
    'base': "u",
        'letters': /(&#117;|&#9444;|&#65365;|&#249;|&#250;|&#251;|&#361;|&#7801;|&#363;|&#7803;|&#365;|&#252;|&#476;|&#472;|&#470;|&#474;|&#7911;|&#367;|&#369;|&#468;|&#533;|&#535;|&#432;|&#7915;|&#7913;|&#7919;|&#7917;|&#7921;|&#7909;|&#7795;|&#371;|&#7799;|&#7797;|&#649;|[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289])/g
}, {
    'base': "v",
        'letters': /(&#118;|&#9445;|&#65366;|&#7805;|&#7807;|&#651;|&#42847;|&#652;|[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C])/g
}, {
    'base': "vy",
        'letters': /(&#42849;|[\uA761])/g
}, {
    'base': "w",
        'letters': /(&#119;|&#9446;|&#65367;|&#7809;|&#7811;|&#373;|&#7815;|&#7813;|&#7832;|&#7817;|&#11379;|[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73])/g
}, {
    'base': "x",
        'letters': /(&#120;|&#9447;|&#65368;|&#7819;|&#7821;|[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D])/g
}, {
    'base': "y",
        'letters': /(&#121;|&#9448;|&#65369;|&#7923;|&#253;|&#375;|&#7929;|&#563;|&#7823;|&#255;|&#7927;|&#7833;|&#7925;|&#436;|&#591;|&#7935;|[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF])/g
}, {
    'base': "z",
        'letters': /(&#122;|&#9449;|&#65370;|&#378;|&#7825;|&#380;|&#382;|&#7827;|&#7829;|&#438;|&#549;|&#576;|&#11372;|&#42851;|[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763])/g
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Tested **fastest** way to remove diacritics from the string that
covers almost all characters. Came to know that this is the best performing method among all others

Diacritics Map

```
var diacriticsMap = {
'\u0041': 'A','\u24B6': 'A','\uFF21': 'A','\u00C0': 'A','\u00C1': 'A','\u00C2': 'A','\u1EA6': 'A','\u1EA4': 'A','\u1EAA': 'A','\u1EA8': 'A',
'\u00C3': 'A','\u0100': 'A','\u0102': 'A','\u1EB0': 'A','\u1EAE': 'A','\u1EB4': 'A','\u1EB2': 'A','\u0226': 'A','\u01E0': 'A','\u00C4': 'A',
'\u01DE': 'A','\u1EA2': 'A','\u00C5': 'A','\u01FA': 'A','\u01CD': 'A','\u0200': 'A','\u0202': 'A','\u1EA0': 'A','\u1EAC': 'A','\u1EB6': 'A',
'\u1E00': 'A','\u0104': 'A','\u023A': 'A','\u2C6F': 'A',

'\uA732': 'AA',
'\u00C6': 'AE','\u01FC': 'AE','\u01E2': 'AE',
'\uA734': 'AO',
'\uA736': 'AU',
'\uA738': 'AV','\uA73A': 'AV',
'\uA73C': 'AY',
'\u0042': 'B','\u24B7': 'B','\uFF22': 'B','\u1E02': 'B','\u1E04': 'B','\u1E06': 'B','\u0243': 'B','\u0182': 'B','\u0181': 'B',

'\u0043': 'C','\u24B8': 'C','\uFF23': 'C','\u0106': 'C','\u0108': 'C','\u010A': 'C','\u010C': 'C','\u00C7': 'C','\u1E08': 'C','\u0187': 'C',
'\u023B': 'C','\uA73E': 'C',

'\u0044': 'D','\u24B9': 'D','\uFF24': 'D','\u1E0A': 'D','\u010E': 'D','\u1E0C': 'D','\u1E10': 'D','\u1E12': 'D','\u1E0E': 'D','\u0110': 'D',
'\u018B': 'D','\u018A': 'D','\u0189': 'D','\uA779': 'D',

'\u01F1': 'DZ','\u01C4': 'DZ',
'\u01F2': 'Dz','\u01C5': 'Dz',

'\u0045': 'E','\u24BA': 'E','\uFF25': 'E','\u00C8': 'E','\u00C9': 'E','\u00CA': 'E','\u1EC0': 'E','\u1EBE': 'E','\u1EC4': 'E','\u1EC2': 'E',
'\u1EBC': 'E','\u0112': 'E','\u1E14': 'E','\u1E16': 'E','\u0114': 'E','\u0116': 'E','\u00CB': 'E','\u1EBA': 'E','\u011A': 'E','\u0204': 'E',
'\u0206': 'E','\u1EB8': 'E','\u1EC6': 'E','\u0228': 'E','\u1E1C': 'E','\u0118': 'E','\u1E18': 'E','\u1E1A': 'E','\u0190': 'E','\u018E': 'E',

'\u0046': 'F','\u24BB': 'F','\uFF26': 'F','\u1E1E': 'F','\u0191': 'F','\uA77B': 'F',

'\u0047': 'G','\u24BC': 'G','\uFF27': 'G','\u01F4': 'G','\u011C': 'G','\u1E20': 'G','\u011E': 'G','\u0120': 'G','\u01E6': 'G','\u0122': 'G',
'\u01E4': 'G','\u0193': 'G','\uA7A0': 'G','\uA77D': 'G','\uA77E': 'G',

'\u0048': 'H','\u24BD': 'H','\uFF28': 'H','\u0124': 'H','\u1E22': 'H','\u1E26': 'H','\u021E': 'H','\u1E24': 'H','\u1E28': 'H','\u1E2A': 'H',
'\u0126': 'H','\u2C67': 'H','\u2C75': 'H','\uA78D': 'H',

'\u0049': 'I','\u24BE': 'I','\uFF29': 'I','\u00CC': 'I','\u00CD': 'I','\u00CE': 'I','\u0128': 'I','\u012A': 'I','\u012C': 'I','\u0130': 'I',
'\u00CF': 'I','\u1E2E': 'I','\u1EC8': 'I','\u01CF': 'I','\u0208': 'I','\u020A': 'I','\u1ECA': 'I','\u012E': 'I','\u1E2C': 'I','\u0197': 'I',

'\u004A': 'J','\u24BF': 'J','\uFF2A': 'J','\u0134': 'J','\u0248': 'J',

'\u004B': 'K','\u24C0': 'K','\uFF2B': 'K','\u1E30': 'K','\u01E8': 'K','\u1E32': 'K','\u0136': 'K','\u1E34': 'K','\u0198': 'K','\u2C69': 'K',
'\uA740': 'K','\uA742': 'K','\uA744': 'K','\uA7A2': 'K',

'\u004C': 'L','\u24C1': 'L','\uFF2C': 'L','\u013F': 'L','\u0139': 'L','\u013D': 'L','\u1E36': 'L','\u1E38': 'L','\u013B': 'L','\u1E3C': 'L',
'\u1E3A': 'L','\u0141': 'L','\u023D': 'L','\u2C62': 'L','\u2C60': 'L','\uA748': 'L','\uA746': 'L','\uA780': 'L',

'\u01C7': 'LJ',
'\u01C8': 'Lj',
'\u004D': 'M','\u24C2': 'M','\uFF2D': 'M','\u1E3E': 'M','\u1E40': 'M','\u1E42': 'M','\u2C6E': 'M','\u019C': 'M',

'\u004E': 'N','\u24C3': 'N','\uFF2E': 'N','\u01F8': 'N','\u0143': 'N','\u00D1': 'N','\u1E44': 'N','\u0147': 'N','\u1E46': 'N','\u0145': 'N',
'\u1E4A': 'N','\u1E48': 'N','\u0220': 'N','\u019D': 'N','\uA790': 'N','\uA7A4': 'N',

'\u01CA': 'NJ',
'\u01CB': 'Nj',

'\u004F': 'O','\u24C4': 'O','\uFF2F': 'O','\u00D2': 'O','\u00D3': 'O','\u00D4': 'O','\u1ED2': 'O','\u1ED0': 'O','\u1ED6': 'O','\u1ED4': 'O',
'\u00D5': 'O','\u1E4C': 'O','\u022C': 'O','\u1E4E': 'O','\u014C': 'O','\u1E50': 'O','\u1E52': 'O','\u014E': 'O','\u022E': 'O','\u0230': 'O',
'\u00D6': 'O','\u022A': 'O','\u1ECE': 'O','\u0150': 'O','\u01D1': 'O','\u020C': 'O','\u020E': 'O','\u01A0': 'O','\u1EDC': 'O','\u1EDA': 'O',
'\u1EE0': 'O','\u1EDE': 'O','\u1EE2': 'O','\u1ECC': 'O','\u1ED8': 'O','\u01EA': 'O','\u01EC': 'O','\u00D8': 'O','\u01FE': 'O','\u0186': 'O',
'\u019F': 'O','\uA74A': 'O','\uA74C': 'O',

'\u01A2': 'OI',
'\uA74E': 'OO',
'\u0222': 'OU',
'\u0050': 'P','\u24C5': 'P','\uFF30': 'P','\u1E54': 'P','\u1E56': 'P','\u01A4': 'P','\u2C63': 'P','\uA750': 'P','\uA752': 'P','\uA754': 'P',
'\u0051': 'Q','\u24C6': 'Q','\uFF31': 'Q','\uA756': 'Q','\uA758': 'Q','\u024A': 'Q',

'\u0052': 'R','\u24C7': 'R','\uFF32': 'R','\u0154': 'R','\u1E58': 'R','\u0158': 'R','\u0210': 'R','\u0212': 'R','\u1E5A': 'R','\u1E5C': 'R',
'\u0156': 'R','\u1E5E': 'R','\u024C': 'R','\u2C64': 'R','\uA75A': 'R','\uA7A6': 'R','\uA782': 'R',

'\u0053': 'S','\u24C8': 'S','\uFF33': 'S','\u1E9E': 'S','\u015A': 'S','\u1E64': 'S','\u015C': 'S','\u1E60': 'S','\u0160': 'S','\u1E66': 'S',
'\u1E62': 'S','\u1E68': 'S','\u0218': 'S','\u015E': 'S','\u2C7E': 'S','\uA7A8': 'S','\uA784': 'S',

'\u0054': 'T','\u24C9': 'T','\uFF34': 'T','\u1E6A': 'T','\u0164': 'T','\u1E6C': 'T','\u021A': 'T','\u0162': 'T','\u1E70': 'T','\u1E6E': 'T',
'\u0166': 'T','\u01AC': 'T','\u01AE': 'T','\u023E': 'T','\uA786': 'T',

'\uA728': 'TZ',

'\u0055': 'U','\u24CA': 'U','\uFF35': 'U','\u00D9': 'U','\u00DA': 'U','\u00DB': 'U','\u0168': 'U','\u1E78': 'U','\u016A': 'U','\u1E7A': 'U',
'\u016C': 'U','\u00DC': 'U','\u01DB': 'U','\u01D7': 'U','\u01D5': 'U','\u01D9': 'U','\u1EE6': 'U','\u016E': 'U','\u0170': 'U','\u01D3': 'U',
'\u0214': 'U','\u0216': 'U','\u01AF': 'U','\u1EEA': 'U','\u1EE8': 'U','\u1EEE': 'U','\u1EEC': 'U','\u1EF0': 'U','\u1EE4': 'U','\u1E72': 'U',
'\u0172': 'U','\u1E76': 'U','\u1E74': 'U','\u0244': 'U',

'\u0056': 'V','\u24CB': 'V','\uFF36': 'V','\u1E7C': 'V','\u1E7E': 'V','\u01B2': 'V','\uA75E': 'V','\u0245': 'V',
'\uA760': 'VY',
'\u0057': 'W','\u24CC': 'W','\uFF37': 'W','\u1E80': 'W','\u1E82': 'W','\u0174': 'W','\u1E86': 'W','\u1E84': 'W','\u1E88': 'W','\u2C72': 'W',
'\u0058': 'X','\u24CD': 'X','\uFF38': 'X','\u1E8A': 'X','\u1E8C': 'X',

'\u0059': 'Y','\u24CE': 'Y','\uFF39': 'Y','\u1EF2': 'Y','\u00DD': 'Y','\u0176': 'Y','\u1EF8': 'Y','\u0232': 'Y','\u1E8E': 'Y','\u0178': 'Y',
'\u1EF6': 'Y','\u1EF4': 'Y','\u01B3': 'Y','\u024E': 'Y','\u1EFE': 'Y',

'\u005A': 'Z','\u24CF': 'Z','\uFF3A': 'Z','\u0179': 'Z','\u1E90': 'Z','\u017B': 'Z','\u017D': 'Z','\u1E92': 'Z','\u1E94': 'Z','\u01B5': 'Z',
'\u0224': 'Z','\u2C7F': 'Z','\u2C6B': 'Z','\uA762': 'Z',

'\u0061': 'a','\u24D0': 'a','\uFF41': 'a','\u1E9A': 'a','\u00E0': 'a','\u00E1': 'a','\u00E2': 'a','\u1EA7': 'a','\u1EA5': 'a','\u1EAB': 'a',
'\u1EA9': 'a','\u00E3': 'a','\u0101': 'a','\u0103': 'a','\u1EB1': 'a','\u1EAF': 'a','\u1EB5': 'a','\u1EB3': 'a','\u0227': 'a','\u01E1': 'a',
'\u00E4': 'a','\u01DF': 'a','\u1EA3': 'a','\u00E5': 'a','\u01FB': 'a','\u01CE': 'a','\u0201': 'a','\u0203': 'a','\u1EA1': 'a','\u1EAD': 'a',
'\u1EB7': 'a','\u1E01': 'a','\u0105': 'a','\u2C65': 'a','\u0250': 'a',

'\uA733': 'aa',
'\u00E6': 'ae','\u01FD': 'ae','\u01E3': 'ae',
'\uA735': 'ao',
'\uA737': 'au',
'\uA739': 'av','\uA73B': 'av',
'\uA73D': 'ay',
'\u0062': 'b','\u24D1': 'b','\uFF42': 'b','\u1E03': 'b','\u1E05': 'b','\u1E07': 'b','\u0180': 'b','\u0183': 'b','\u0253': 'b',

'\u0063': 'c','\u24D2': 'c','\uFF43': 'c','\u0107': 'c','\u0109': 'c','\u010B': 'c','\u010D': 'c','\u00E7': 'c','\u1E09': 'c','\u0188': 'c',
'\u023C': 'c','\uA73F': 'c','\u2184': 'c',

'\u0064': 'd','\u24D3': 'd','\uFF44': 'd','\u1E0B': 'd','\u010F': 'd','\u1E0D': 'd','\u1E11': 'd','\u1E13': 'd','\u1E0F': 'd','\u0111': 'd',
'\u018C': 'd','\u0256': 'd','\u0257': 'd','\uA77A': 'd',

'\u01F3': 'dz','\u01C6': 'dz',

'\u0065': 'e','\u24D4': 'e','\uFF45': 'e','\u00E8': 'e','\u00E9': 'e','\u00EA': 'e','\u1EC1': 'e','\u1EBF': 'e','\u1EC5': 'e','\u1EC3': 'e',
'\u1EBD': 'e','\u0113': 'e','\u1E15': 'e','\u1E17': 'e','\u0115': 'e','\u0117': 'e','\u00EB': 'e','\u1EBB': 'e','\u011B': 'e','\u0205': 'e',
'\u0207': 'e','\u1EB9': 'e','\u1EC7': 'e','\u0229': 'e','\u1E1D': 'e','\u0119': 'e','\u1E19': 'e','\u1E1B': 'e','\u0247': 'e','\u025B': 'e',
'\u01DD': 'e',

'\u0066': 'f','\u24D5': 'f','\uFF46': 'f','\u1E1F': 'f','\u0192': 'f','\uA77C': 'f',

'\u0067': 'g','\u24D6': 'g','\uFF47': 'g','\u01F5': 'g','\u011D': 'g','\u1E21': 'g','\u011F': 'g','\u0121': 'g','\u01E7': 'g','\u0123': 'g',
'\u01E5': 'g','\u0260': 'g','\uA7A1': 'g','\u1D79': 'g','\uA77F': 'g',

'\u0068': 'h','\u24D7': 'h','\uFF48': 'h','\u0125': 'h','\u1E23': 'h','\u1E27': 'h','\u021F': 'h','\u1E25': 'h','\u1E29': 'h','\u1E2B': 'h',
'\u1E96': 'h','\u0127': 'h','\u2C68': 'h','\u2C76': 'h','\u0265': 'h',

'\u0195': 'hv',

'\u0069': 'i','\u24D8': 'i','\uFF49': 'i','\u00EC': 'i','\u00ED': 'i','\u00EE': 'i','\u0129': 'i','\u012B': 'i','\u012D': 'i','\u00EF': 'i',
'\u1E2F': 'i','\u1EC9': 'i','\u01D0': 'i','\u0209': 'i','\u020B': 'i','\u1ECB': 'i','\u012F': 'i','\u1E2D': 'i','\u0268': 'i','\u0131': 'i',

'\u006A': 'j','\u24D9': 'j','\uFF4A': 'j','\u0135': 'j','\u01F0': 'j','\u0249': 'j',

'\u006B': 'k','\u24DA': 'k','\uFF4B': 'k','\u1E31': 'k','\u01E9': 'k','\u1E33': 'k','\u0137': 'k','\u1E35': 'k','\u0199': 'k','\u2C6A': 'k',
'\uA741': 'k','\uA743': 'k','\uA745': 'k','\uA7A3': 'k',

'\u006C': 'l','\u24DB': 'l','\uFF4C': 'l','\u0140': 'l','\u013A': 'l','\u013E': 'l','\u1E37': 'l','\u1E39': 'l','\u013C': 'l','\u1E3D': 'l',
'\u1E3B': 'l','\u017F': 'l','\u0142': 'l','\u019A': 'l','\u026B': 'l','\u2C61': 'l','\uA749': 'l','\uA781': 'l','\uA747': 'l',

'\u01C9': 'lj',
'\u006D': 'm','\u24DC': 'm','\uFF4D': 'm','\u1E3F': 'm','\u1E41': 'm','\u1E43': 'm','\u0271': 'm','\u026F': 'm',

'\u006E': 'n','\u24DD': 'n','\uFF4E': 'n','\u01F9': 'n','\u0144': 'n','\u00F1': 'n','\u1E45': 'n','\u0148': 'n','\u1E47': 'n','\u0146': 'n',
'\u1E4B': 'n','\u1E49': 'n','\u019E': 'n','\u0272': 'n','\u0149': 'n','\uA791': 'n','\uA7A5': 'n',

'\u01CC': 'nj',

'\u006F': 'o','\u24DE': 'o','\uFF4F': 'o','\u00F2': 'o','\u00F3': 'o','\u00F4': 'o','\u1ED3': 'o','\u1ED1': 'o','\u1ED7': 'o','\u1ED5': 'o',
'\u00F5': 'o','\u1E4D': 'o','\u022D': 'o','\u1E4F': 'o','\u014D': 'o','\u1E51': 'o','\u1E53': 'o','\u014F': 'o','\u022F': 'o','\u0231': 'o',
'\u00F6': 'o','\u022B': 'o','\u1ECF': 'o','\u0151': 'o','\u01D2': 'o','\u020D': 'o','\u020F': 'o','\u01A1': 'o','\u1EDD': 'o','\u1EDB': 'o',
'\u1EE1': 'o','\u1EDF': 'o','\u1EE3': 'o','\u1ECD': 'o','\u1ED9': 'o','\u01EB': 'o','\u01ED': 'o','\u00F8': 'o','\u01FF': 'o','\u0254': 'o',
'\uA74B': 'o','\uA74D': 'o','\u0275': 'o',

'\u01A3': 'oi',
'\u0223': 'ou',
'\uA74F': 'oo',
'\u0070': 'p','\u24DF': 'p','\uFF50': 'p','\u1E55': 'p','\u1E57': 'p','\u01A5': 'p','\u1D7D': 'p','\uA751': 'p','\uA753': 'p','\uA755': 'p',
'\u0071': 'q','\u24E0': 'q','\uFF51': 'q','\u024B': 'q','\uA757': 'q','\uA759': 'q',

'\u0072': 'r','\u24E1': 'r','\uFF52': 'r','\u0155': 'r','\u1E59': 'r','\u0159': 'r','\u0211': 'r','\u0213': 'r','\u1E5B': 'r','\u1E5D': 'r',
'\u0157': 'r','\u1E5F': 'r','\u024D': 'r','\u027D': 'r','\uA75B': 'r','\uA7A7': 'r','\uA783': 'r',

'\u0073': 's','\u24E2': 's','\uFF53': 's','\u00DF': 's','\u015B': 's','\u1E65': 's','\u015D': 's','\u1E61': 's','\u0161': 's','\u1E67': 's',
'\u1E63': 's','\u1E69': 's','\u0219': 's','\u015F': 's','\u023F': 's','\uA7A9': 's','\uA785': 's','\u1E9B': 's',

'\u0074': 't','\u24E3': 't','\uFF54': 't','\u1E6B': 't','\u1E97': 't','\u0165': 't','\u1E6D': 't','\u021B': 't','\u0163': 't','\u1E71': 't',
'\u1E6F': 't','\u0167': 't','\u01AD': 't','\u0288': 't','\u2C66': 't','\uA787': 't',

'\uA729': 'tz',

'\u0075': 'u','\u24E4': 'u','\uFF55': 'u','\u00F9': 'u','\u00FA': 'u','\u00FB': 'u','\u0169': 'u','\u1E79': 'u','\u016B': 'u','\u1E7B': 'u',
'\u016D': 'u','\u00FC': 'u','\u01DC': 'u','\u01D8': 'u','\u01D6': 'u','\u01DA': 'u','\u1EE7': 'u','\u016F': 'u','\u0171': 'u','\u01D4': 'u',
'\u0215': 'u','\u0217': 'u','\u01B0': 'u','\u1EEB': 'u','\u1EE9': 'u','\u1EEF': 'u','\u1EED': 'u','\u1EF1': 'u','\u1EE5': 'u','\u1E73': 'u',
'\u0173': 'u','\u1E77': 'u','\u1E75': 'u','\u0289': 'u',

'\u0076': 'v','\u24E5': 'v','\uFF56': 'v','\u1E7D': 'v','\u1E7F': 'v','\u028B': 'v','\uA75F': 'v','\u028C': 'v',
'\uA761': 'vy',
'\u0077': 'w','\u24E6': 'w','\uFF57': 'w','\u1E81': 'w','\u1E83': 'w','\u0175': 'w','\u1E87': 'w','\u1E85': 'w','\u1E98': 'w','\u1E89': 'w',
'\u2C73': 'w',
'\u0078': 'x','\u24E7': 'x','\uFF58': 'x','\u1E8B': 'x','\u1E8D': 'x',

'\u0079': 'y','\u24E8': 'y','\uFF59': 'y','\u1EF3': 'y','\u00FD': 'y','\u0177': 'y','\u1EF9': 'y','\u0233': 'y','\u1E8F': 'y','\u00FF': 'y',
'\u1EF7': 'y','\u1E99': 'y','\u1EF5': 'y','\u01B4': 'y','\u024F': 'y','\u1EFF': 'y',

'\u007A': 'z','\u24E9': 'z','\uFF5A': 'z','\u017A': 'z','\u1E91': 'z','\u017C': 'z','\u017E': 'z','\u1E93': 'z','\u1E95': 'z','\u01B6': 'z',
'\u0225': 'z','\u0240': 'z','\u2C6C': 'z','\uA763': 'z',
};
```

Use

```
function removeDicretics(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function (weirdo) {
        return diacriticsMap[weirdo] || weirdo;
    });
}
// Call
var cleanStr = removeDicretics("bułłśhìt"); // bullshit
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my modified version of [lehelk.com](http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/)'s version that also removes html entites that are accents :

http://jsfiddle.net/billybraga/UHmnf/

I still don't know about performance, though...

```
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [{
    'base': "A",
    'letters': /(&#65;|&#9398;|&#65313;|&#192;|&#193;|&#194;|&#7846;|&#7844;|&#7850;|&#7848;|&#195;|&#256;|&#258;|&#7856;|&#7854;|&#7860;|&#7858;|&#550;|&#480;|&#196;|&#478;|&#7842;|&#197;|&#506;|&#461;|&#512;|&#514;|&#7840;|&#7852;|&#7862;|&#7680;|&#260;|&#570;|&#11375;|[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F])/g},
{
    'base': "AA",
    'letters': /(&#42802;|[\uA732])/g},
{
    'base': "AE",
    'letters': /(&#198;|&#508;|&#482;|[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2])/g},
{
    'base': "AO",
    'letters': /(&#42804;|[\uA734])/g},
{
    'base': "AU",
    'letters': /(&#42806;|[\uA736])/g},
{
    'base': "AV",
    'letters': /(&#42808;|&#42810;|[\uA738\uA73A])/g},
{
    'base': "AY",
    'letters': /(&#42812;|[\uA73C])/g},
{
    'base': "B",
    'letters': /(&#66;|&#9399;|&#65314;|&#7682;|&#7684;|&#7686;|&#579;|&#386;|&#385;|[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181])/g},
{
    'base': "C",
    'letters': /(&#67;|&#9400;|&#65315;|&#262;|&#264;|&#266;|&#268;|&#199;|&#7688;|&#391;|&#571;|&#42814;|[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E])/g},
{
    'base': "D",
    'letters': /(&#68;|&#9401;|&#65316;|&#7690;|&#270;|&#7692;|&#7696;|&#7698;|&#7694;|&#272;|&#395;|&#394;|&#393;|&#42873;|[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779])/g},
{
    'base': "DZ",
    'letters': /(&#497;|&#452;|[\u01F1\u01C4])/g},
{
    'base': "Dz",
    'letters': /(&#498;|&#453;|[\u01F2\u01C5])/g},
{
    'base': "E",
    'letters': /(&#69;|&#9402;|&#65317;|&#200;|&#201;|&#202;|&#7872;|&#7870;|&#7876;|&#7874;|&#7868;|&#274;|&#7700;|&#7702;|&#276;|&#278;|&#203;|&#7866;|&#282;|&#516;|&#518;|&#7864;|&#7878;|&#552;|&#7708;|&#280;|&#7704;|&#7706;|&#400;|&#398;|[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E])/g},
{
    'base': "F",
    'letters': /(&#70;|&#9403;|&#65318;|&#7710;|&#401;|&#42875;|[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B])/g},
{
    'base': "G",
    'letters': /(&#71;|&#9404;|&#65319;|&#500;|&#284;|&#7712;|&#286;|&#288;|&#486;|&#290;|&#484;|&#403;|&#42912;|&#42877;|&#42878;|[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E])/g},
{
    'base': "H",
    'letters': /(&#72;|&#9405;|&#65320;|&#292;|&#7714;|&#7718;|&#542;|&#7716;|&#7720;|&#7722;|&#294;|&#11367;|&#11381;|&#42893;|[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D])/g},
{
    'base': "I",
    'letters': /(&#73;|&#9406;|&#65321;|&#204;|&#205;|&#206;|&#296;|&#298;|&#300;|&#304;|&#207;|&#7726;|&#7880;|&#463;|&#520;|&#522;|&#7882;|&#302;|&#7724;|&#407;|[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197])/g},
{
    'base': "J",
    'letters': /(&#74;|&#9407;|&#65322;|&#308;|&#584;|[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248])/g},
{
    'base': "K",
    'letters': /(&#75;|&#9408;|&#65323;|&#7728;|&#488;|&#7730;|&#310;|&#7732;|&#408;|&#11369;|&#42816;|&#42818;|&#42820;|&#42914;|[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2])/g},
{
    'base': "L",
    'letters': /(&#76;|&#9409;|&#65324;|&#319;|&#313;|&#317;|&#7734;|&#7736;|&#315;|&#7740;|&#7738;|&#321;|&#573;|&#11362;|&#11360;|&#42824;|&#42822;|&#42880;|[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780])/g},
{
    'base': "LJ",
    'letters': /(&#455;|[\u01C7])/g},
{
    'base': "Lj",
    'letters': /(&#456;|[\u01C8])/g},
{
    'base': "M",
    'letters': /(&#77;|&#9410;|&#65325;|&#7742;|&#7744;|&#7746;|&#11374;|&#412;|[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C])/g},
{
    'base': "N",
    'letters': /(&#78;|&#9411;|&#65326;|&#504;|&#323;|&#209;|&#7748;|&#327;|&#7750;|&#325;|&#7754;|&#7752;|&#544;|&#413;|&#42896;|&#42916;|[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4])/g},
{
    'base': "NJ",
    'letters': /(&#458;|[\u01CA])/g},
{
    'base': "Nj",
    'letters': /(&#459;|[\u01CB])/g},
{
    'base': "O",
    'letters': /(&#79;|&#9412;|&#65327;|&#210;|&#211;|&#212;|&#7890;|&#7888;|&#7894;|&#7892;|&#213;|&#7756;|&#556;|&#7758;|&#332;|&#7760;|&#7762;|&#334;|&#558;|&#560;|&#214;|&#554;|&#7886;|&#336;|&#465;|&#524;|&#526;|&#416;|&#7900;|&#7898;|&#7904;|&#7902;|&#7906;|&#7884;|&#7896;|&#490;|&#492;|&#216;|&#510;|&#390;|&#415;|&#42826;|&#42828;|[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C])/g},
{
    'base': "OI",
    'letters': /(&#418;|[\u01A2])/g},
{
    'base': "OO",
    'letters': /(&#42830;|[\uA74E])/g},
{
    'base': "OU",
    'letters': /(&#546;|[\u0222])/g},
{
    'base': "P",
    'letters': /(&#80;|&#9413;|&#65328;|&#7764;|&#7766;|&#420;|&#11363;|&#42832;|&#42834;|&#42836;|[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754])/g},
{
    'base': "Q",
    'letters': /(&#81;|&#9414;|&#65329;|&#42838;|&#42840;|&#586;|[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A])/g},
{
    'base': "R",
    'letters': /(&#82;|&#9415;|&#65330;|&#340;|&#7768;|&#344;|&#528;|&#530;|&#7770;|&#7772;|&#342;|&#7774;|&#588;|&#11364;|&#42842;|&#42918;|&#42882;|[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782])/g},
{
    'base': "S",
    'letters': /(&#83;|&#9416;|&#65331;|&#7838;|&#346;|&#7780;|&#348;|&#7776;|&#352;|&#7782;|&#7778;|&#7784;|&#536;|&#350;|&#11390;|&#42920;|&#42884;|[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784])/g},
{
    'base': "T",
    'letters': /(&#84;|&#9417;|&#65332;|&#7786;|&#356;|&#7788;|&#538;|&#354;|&#7792;|&#7790;|&#358;|&#428;|&#430;|&#574;|&#42886;|[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786])/g},
{
    'base': "TZ",
    'letters': /(&#42792;|[\uA728])/g},
{
    'base': "U",
    'letters': /(&#85;|&#9418;|&#65333;|&#217;|&#218;|&#219;|&#360;|&#7800;|&#362;|&#7802;|&#364;|&#220;|&#475;|&#471;|&#469;|&#473;|&#7910;|&#366;|&#368;|&#467;|&#532;|&#534;|&#431;|&#7914;|&#7912;|&#7918;|&#7916;|&#7920;|&#7908;|&#7794;|&#370;|&#7798;|&#7796;|&#580;|[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244])/g},
{
    'base': "V",
    'letters': /(&#86;|&#9419;|&#65334;|&#7804;|&#7806;|&#434;|&#42846;|&#581;|[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245])/g},
{
    'base': "VY",
    'letters': /(&#42848;|[\uA760])/g},
{
    'base': "W",
    'letters': /(&#87;|&#9420;|&#65335;|&#7808;|&#7810;|&#372;|&#7814;|&#7812;|&#7816;|&#11378;|[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72])/g},
{
    'base': "X",
    'letters': /(&#88;|&#9421;|&#65336;|&#7818;|&#7820;|[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C])/g},
{
    'base': "Y",
    'letters': /(&#89;|&#9422;|&#65337;|&#7922;|&#221;|&#374;|&#7928;|&#562;|&#7822;|&#376;|&#7926;|&#7924;|&#435;|&#590;|&#7934;|[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE])/g},
{
    'base': "Z",
    'letters': /(&#90;|&#9423;|&#65338;|&#377;|&#7824;|&#379;|&#381;|&#7826;|&#7828;|&#437;|&#548;|&#11391;|&#11371;|&#42850;|[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762])/g},
{
    'base': "a",
    'letters': /(&#97;|&#9424;|&#65345;|&#7834;|&#224;|&#225;|&#226;|&#7847;|&#7845;|&#7851;|&#7849;|&#227;|&#257;|&#259;|&#7857;|&#7855;|&#7861;|&#7859;|&#551;|&#481;|&#228;|&#479;|&#7843;|&#229;|&#507;|&#462;|&#513;|&#515;|&#7841;|&#7853;|&#7863;|&#7681;|&#261;|&#11365;|&#592;|[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250])/g},
{
    'base': "aa",
    'letters': /(&#42803;|[\uA733])/g},
{
    'base': "ae",
    'letters': /(&#230;|&#509;|&#483;|[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3])/g},
{
    'base': "ao",
    'letters': /(&#42805;|[\uA735])/g},
{
    'base': "au",
    'letters': /(&#42807;|[\uA737])/g},
{
    'base': "av",
    'letters': /(&#42809;|&#42811;|[\uA739\uA73B])/g},
{
    'base': "ay",
    'letters': /(&#42813;|[\uA73D])/g},
{
    'base': "b",
    'letters': /(&#98;|&#9425;|&#65346;|&#7683;|&#7685;|&#7687;|&#384;|&#387;|&#595;|[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253])/g},
{
    'base': "c",
    'letters': /(&#99;|&#9426;|&#65347;|&#263;|&#265;|&#267;|&#269;|&#231;|&#7689;|&#392;|&#572;|&#42815;|&#8580;|[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184])/g},
{
    'base': "d",
    'letters': /(&#100;|&#9427;|&#65348;|&#7691;|&#271;|&#7693;|&#7697;|&#7699;|&#7695;|&#273;|&#396;|&#598;|&#599;|&#42874;|[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A])/g},
{
    'base': "dz",
    'letters': /(&#499;|&#454;|[\u01F3\u01C6])/g},
{
    'base': "e",
    'letters': /(&#101;|&#9428;|&#65349;|&#232;|&#233;|&#234;|&#7873;|&#7871;|&#7877;|&#7875;|&#7869;|&#275;|&#7701;|&#7703;|&#277;|&#279;|&#235;|&#7867;|&#283;|&#517;|&#519;|&#7865;|&#7879;|&#553;|&#7709;|&#281;|&#7705;|&#7707;|&#583;|&#603;|&#477;|[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD])/g},
{
    'base': "f",
    'letters': /(&#102;|&#9429;|&#65350;|&#7711;|&#402;|&#42876;|[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C])/g},
{
    'base': "g",
    'letters': /(&#103;|&#9430;|&#65351;|&#501;|&#285;|&#7713;|&#287;|&#289;|&#487;|&#291;|&#485;|&#608;|&#42913;|&#7545;|&#42879;|[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F])/g},
{
    'base': "h",
    'letters': /(&#104;|&#9431;|&#65352;|&#293;|&#7715;|&#7719;|&#543;|&#7717;|&#7721;|&#7723;|&#7830;|&#295;|&#11368;|&#11382;|&#613;|[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265])/g},
{
    'base': "hv",
    'letters': /(&#405;|[\u0195])/g},
{
    'base': "i",
    'letters': /(&#105;|&#9432;|&#65353;|&#236;|&#237;|&#238;|&#297;|&#299;|&#301;|&#239;|&#7727;|&#7881;|&#464;|&#521;|&#523;|&#7883;|&#303;|&#7725;|&#616;|&#305;|[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131])/g},
{
    'base': "j",
    'letters': /(&#106;|&#9433;|&#65354;|&#309;|&#496;|&#585;|[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249])/g},
{
    'base': "k",
    'letters': /(&#107;|&#9434;|&#65355;|&#7729;|&#489;|&#7731;|&#311;|&#7733;|&#409;|&#11370;|&#42817;|&#42819;|&#42821;|&#42915;|[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3])/g},
{
    'base': "l",
    'letters': /(&#108;|&#9435;|&#65356;|&#320;|&#314;|&#318;|&#7735;|&#7737;|&#316;|&#7741;|&#7739;|&#383;|&#322;|&#410;|&#619;|&#11361;|&#42825;|&#42881;|&#42823;|[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747])/g},
{
    'base': "lj",
    'letters': /(&#457;|[\u01C9])/g},
{
    'base': "m",
    'letters': /(&#109;|&#9436;|&#65357;|&#7743;|&#7745;|&#7747;|&#625;|&#623;|[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F])/g},
{
    'base': "n",
    'letters': /(&#110;|&#9437;|&#65358;|&#505;|&#324;|&#241;|&#7749;|&#328;|&#7751;|&#326;|&#7755;|&#7753;|&#414;|&#626;|&#329;|&#42897;|&#42917;|[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5])/g},
{
    'base': "nj",
    'letters': /(&#460;|[\u01CC])/g},
{
    'base': "o",
    'letters': /(&#111;|&#9438;|&#65359;|&#242;|&#243;|&#244;|&#7891;|&#7889;|&#7895;|&#7893;|&#245;|&#7757;|&#557;|&#7759;|&#333;|&#7761;|&#7763;|&#335;|&#559;|&#561;|&#246;|&#555;|&#7887;|&#337;|&#466;|&#525;|&#527;|&#417;|&#7901;|&#7899;|&#7905;|&#7903;|&#7907;|&#7885;|&#7897;|&#491;|&#493;|&#248;|&#511;|&#596;|&#42827;|&#42829;|&#629;|[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275])/g},
{
    'base': "oi",
    'letters': /(&#419;|[\u01A3])/g},
{
    'base': "ou",
    'letters': /(&#547;|[\u0223])/g},
{
    'base': "oo",
    'letters': /(&#42831;|[\uA74F])/g},
{
    'base': "p",
    'letters': /(&#112;|&#9439;|&#65360;|&#7765;|&#7767;|&#421;|&#7549;|&#42833;|&#42835;|&#42837;|[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755])/g},
{
    'base': "q",
    'letters': /(&#113;|&#9440;|&#65361;|&#587;|&#42839;|&#42841;|[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759])/g},
{
    'base': "r",
    'letters': /(&#114;|&#9441;|&#65362;|&#341;|&#7769;|&#345;|&#529;|&#531;|&#7771;|&#7773;|&#343;|&#7775;|&#589;|&#637;|&#42843;|&#42919;|&#42883;|[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783])/g},
{
    'base': "s",
    'letters': /(&#115;|&#9442;|&#65363;|&#223;|&#347;|&#7781;|&#349;|&#7777;|&#353;|&#7783;|&#7779;|&#7785;|&#537;|&#351;|&#575;|&#42921;|&#42885;|&#7835;|[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B])/g},
{
    'base': "t",
    'letters': /(&#116;|&#9443;|&#65364;|&#7787;|&#7831;|&#357;|&#7789;|&#539;|&#355;|&#7793;|&#7791;|&#359;|&#429;|&#648;|&#11366;|&#42887;|[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787])/g},
{
    'base': "tz",
    'letters': /(&#42793;|[\uA729])/g},
{
    'base': "u",
    'letters': /(&#117;|&#9444;|&#65365;|&#249;|&#250;|&#251;|&#361;|&#7801;|&#363;|&#7803;|&#365;|&#252;|&#476;|&#472;|&#470;|&#474;|&#7911;|&#367;|&#369;|&#468;|&#533;|&#535;|&#432;|&#7915;|&#7913;|&#7919;|&#7917;|&#7921;|&#7909;|&#7795;|&#371;|&#7799;|&#7797;|&#649;|[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289])/g},
{
    'base': "v",
    'letters': /(&#118;|&#9445;|&#65366;|&#7805;|&#7807;|&#651;|&#42847;|&#652;|[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C])/g},
{
    'base': "vy",
    'letters': /(&#42849;|[\uA761])/g},
{
    'base': "w",
    'letters': /(&#119;|&#9446;|&#65367;|&#7809;|&#7811;|&#373;|&#7815;|&#7813;|&#7832;|&#7817;|&#11379;|[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73])/g},
{
    'base': "x",
    'letters': /(&#120;|&#9447;|&#65368;|&#7819;|&#7821;|[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D])/g},
{
    'base': "y",
    'letters': /(&#121;|&#9448;|&#65369;|&#7923;|&#253;|&#375;|&#7929;|&#563;|&#7823;|&#255;|&#7927;|&#7833;|&#7925;|&#436;|&#591;|&#7935;|[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF])/g},
{
    'base': "z",
    'letters': /(&#122;|&#9449;|&#65370;|&#378;|&#7825;|&#380;|&#382;|&#7827;|&#7829;|&#438;|&#549;|&#576;|&#11372;|&#42851;|[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763])/g}];

function removeDiacritics(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple solution without too much code using a very simple map of diacritics that includes some or all that map to ascii equivalents containing more than one character, i.e. Æ => AE, ﬃ => ffi, etc...  Also included some very basic functional tests

```
var diacriticsMap = {
  '\u00C0': 'A',  // À => A
  '\u00C1': 'A',   // Á => A
  '\u00C2': 'A',   // Â => A
  '\u00C3': 'A',   // Ã => A
  '\u00C4': 'A',   // Ä => A
  '\u00C5': 'A',   // Å => A
  '\u00C6': 'AE', // Æ => AE
  '\u00C7': 'C',   // Ç => C
  '\u00C8': 'E',   // È => E
  '\u00C9': 'E',   // É => E
  '\u00CA': 'E',   // Ê => E
  '\u00CB': 'E',   // Ë => E
  '\u00CC': 'I',   // Ì => I
  '\u00CD': 'I',   // Í => I
  '\u00CE': 'I',   // Î => I
  '\u00CF': 'I',   // Ï => I
  '\u0132': 'IJ', // Ĳ => IJ
  '\u00D0': 'D',   // Ð => D
  '\u00D1': 'N',   // Ñ => N
  '\u00D2': 'O',   // Ò => O
  '\u00D3': 'O',   // Ó => O
  '\u00D4': 'O',   // Ô => O
  '\u00D5': 'O',   // Õ => O
  '\u00D6': 'O',   // Ö => O
  '\u00D8': 'O',   // Ø => O
  '\u0152': 'OE', // Œ => OE
  '\u00DE': 'TH', // Þ => TH
  '\u00D9': 'U',   // Ù => U
  '\u00DA': 'U',   // Ú => U
  '\u00DB': 'U',   // Û => U
  '\u00DC': 'U',   // Ü => U
  '\u00DD': 'Y',   // Ý => Y
  '\u0178': 'Y',   // Ÿ => Y
  '\u00E0': 'a',   // à => a
  '\u00E1': 'a',   // á => a
  '\u00E2': 'a',   // â => a
  '\u00E3': 'a',   // ã => a
  '\u00E4': 'a',   // ä => a
  '\u00E5': 'a',   // å => a
  '\u00E6': 'ae', // æ => ae
  '\u00E7': 'c',   // ç => c
  '\u00E8': 'e',   // è => e
  '\u00E9': 'e',   // é => e
  '\u00EA': 'e',   // ê => e
  '\u00EB': 'e',   // ë => e
  '\u00EC': 'i',   // ì => i
  '\u00ED': 'i',   // í => i
  '\u00EE': 'i',   // î => i
  '\u00EF': 'i',   // ï => i
  '\u0133': 'ij', // ĳ => ij
  '\u00F0': 'd',   // ð => d
  '\u00F1': 'n',   // ñ => n
  '\u00F2': 'o',   // ò => o
  '\u00F3': 'o',   // ó => o
  '\u00F4': 'o',   // ô => o
  '\u00F5': 'o',   // õ => o
  '\u00F6': 'o',   // ö => o
  '\u00F8': 'o',   // ø => o
  '\u0153': 'oe', // œ => oe
  '\u00DF': 'ss', // ß => ss
  '\u00FE': 'th', // þ => th
  '\u00F9': 'u',   // ù => u
  '\u00FA': 'u',   // ú => u
  '\u00FB': 'u',   // û => u
  '\u00FC': 'u',   // ü => u
  '\u00FD': 'y',   // ý => y
  '\u00FF': 'y',   // ÿ => y
  '\uFB00': 'ff', // ﬀ => ff
  '\uFB01': 'fi',   // ﬁ => fi
  '\uFB02': 'fl', // ﬂ => fl
  '\uFB03': 'ffi',  // ﬃ => ffi
  '\uFB04': 'ffl',  // ﬄ => ffl
  '\uFB05': 'ft', // ﬅ => ft
  '\uFB06': 'st'  // ﬆ => st
};

function replaceDiacritics(str) {
  var returnStr = '';
  if(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (diacriticsMap[str[i]]) {
        returnStr += diacriticsMap[str[i]];
      } else {
        returnStr += str[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return returnStr;
}

function testStripDiacritics(input, expected) {
  var coChar = replaceDiacritics(input);
  console.log('The character passed in was ' + input);
  console.log('The character that came out was ' + coChar);
  console.log('The character expected was' + expected);
}

testStripDiacritics('À','A');
testStripDiacritics('A','A');
testStripDiacritics('Æ','AE');
testStripDiacritics('AE','AE');
testStripDiacritics('ÇhÀrlËšYŸZŽ','ChArlEsYYZZ');
```

Comment: This is far from complete, but your mappings are great for pre-processing search strings because they properly assume what English speakers would type, eg perhaps `Ä` -> `Ae` is correct, but `Ä` -> `A` is more likely what English speakers are going to actually type. I'm going to process my strings with this, followed by the .normalize() function per [Lewis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/2036135). Great that you also catch `Ø` -> `O`, but I shall need to add `ł` -> `l` ;)

Answer (score 3):

[normalize-diacritics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-diacritics) is very useful

```js
const { normalize } = require('normalize-diacritics');
     
// Assuming top-level await is enabled...
await normalize('söme stüff with áccènts'); // 'some stuff with accents'
```

Comment: NB: The actual [source](https://github.com/motss/normalize-diacritics/blob/main/src/index.ts) for normalise-diacritics does the same thing as [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5960592).

Answer (score 2):

thanks to all
I use this version and say why (because I misses those explanations at the begining, so I try to help the next reader if he is as dull as me ...)

Remark : I wanted an efficient solution, so :

- only one regexp compilation (if needed)
- only one string scan for each string
- an efficient way to find the translated characters
  etc ...

My version is :
(there is no new technical trick inside it, only some selected ones + explanations why)

```
makeSortString = (function() {
    var translate_re = /[¹²³áàâãäåaaaÀÁÂÃÄÅAAAÆccç©CCÇÐÐèéê?ëeeeeeÈÊË?EEEEE€gGiìíîïìiiiÌÍÎÏ?ÌIIIlLnnñNNÑòóôõöoooøÒÓÔÕÖOOOØŒr®Ršs?ßŠS?ùúûüuuuuÙÚÛÜUUUUýÿÝŸžzzŽZZ]/g;
    var translate = {
"¹":"1","²":"2","³":"3","á":"a","à":"a","â":"a","ã":"a","ä":"a","å":"a","a":"a","a":"a","a":"a","À":"a","Á":"a","Â":"a","Ã":"a","Ä":"a","Å":"a","A":"a","A":"a",
"A":"a","Æ":"a","c":"c","c":"c","ç":"c","©":"c","C":"c","C":"c","Ç":"c","Ð":"d","Ð":"d","è":"e","é":"e","ê":"e","?":"e","ë":"e","e":"e","e":"e","e":"e","e":"e",
"e":"e","È":"e","Ê":"e","Ë":"e","?":"e","E":"e","E":"e","E":"e","E":"e","E":"e","€":"e","g":"g","G":"g","i":"i","ì":"i","í":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ì":"i","i":"i",
"i":"i","i":"i","Ì":"i","Í":"i","Î":"i","Ï":"i","?":"i","Ì":"i","I":"i","I":"i","I":"i","l":"l","L":"l","n":"n","n":"n","ñ":"n","N":"n","N":"n","Ñ":"n","ò":"o",
"ó":"o","ô":"o","õ":"o","ö":"o","o":"o","o":"o","o":"o","ø":"o","Ò":"o","Ó":"o","Ô":"o","Õ":"o","Ö":"o","O":"o","O":"o","O":"o","Ø":"o","Œ":"o","r":"r","®":"r",
"R":"r","š":"s","s":"s","?":"s","ß":"s","Š":"s","S":"s","?":"s","ù":"u","ú":"u","û":"u","ü":"u","u":"u","u":"u","u":"u","u":"u","Ù":"u","Ú":"u","Û":"u","Ü":"u",
"U":"u","U":"u","U":"u","U":"u","ý":"y","ÿ":"y","Ý":"y","Ÿ":"y","ž":"z","z":"z","z":"z","Ž":"z","Z":"z","Z":"z"
    };
    return function(s) {
        return(s.replace(translate_re, function(match){return translate[match];}) );
    }
})();
```

and I use it this way :

```
var without_accents = makeSortString("wïthêüÄTrèsBïgüeAk100t");
// I let you guess the result,
// no I was kidding you : I give you the result : witheuatresbigueak100t
```

Comments :

- Tthe instruction inside it is done once (after, makeSortString != undefined)
- function(){...} is stored once in makeSortString, so the "big" translate_re and translate objects are stored once
- When you call makeSortString('something') it call directly the inside function which calls only s.replace(...) : it is efficient
- s.replace uses regexp (the special syntax of var translate_re= .... is in fact equivalent to var translate_re = new RegExp("[¹....Z]","g"); but the compilation of the regexp is done once for all, and the scan of the s String is done one for a call of the function (not for every character as it would be in a loop)
- For each character found s.replace calls function(match) where parameter match contains the character found, and it call the corresponding translated character (translate[match])
- Translate[match] is probably efficient too as the javascript translate object is probably implemented by javascript with a hashtab or something equivalent and allow the program to find the translated character almost directly and not for instance through a loop on a array of all characters to find the right one (which would be awfully unefficient).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what you're doing, I suspect IE6 is not interpreting the file's encoding correctly, and hence not recognising the non-ASCII characters in the file:

- Make sure the file is saved as UTF-8 (say)
- Use Fiddler or some other tool to check that the web server is sending the correct Content-Encoding HTTP header.

(It "smells" wrong though, I'd look into doing the sorting, say on the server using something that's locale-aware... but anyway...)

Comment: It's an old question I just edited. You're right, it was a matter of encoding (IE6 does not recognize the charset 'utf-8' but only 'UTF-8'). Although there is no point is making a sorting on the server, especially when you display a long table with several sortable columns. +1 though for the encoding mention which was the final real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found all these a little clumsy and I'm not too expert on regular expressions, so here's a simpler version. It would be quite easy to translate it to your favourite server-side language, assuming that the string already in Unicode:

```
// String containing replacement characters for stripping accents 
var stripstring = 
    'AAAAAAACEEEEIIII'+
    'DNOOOOO.OUUUUY..'+
    'aaaaaaaceeeeiiii'+
    'dnooooo.ouuuuy.y'+
    'AaAaAaCcCcCcCcDd'+
    'DdEeEeEeEeEeGgGg'+
    'GgGgHhHhIiIiIiIi'+
    'IiIiJjKkkLlLlLlL'+
    'lJlNnNnNnnNnOoOo'+
    'OoOoRrRrRrSsSsSs'+
    'SsTtTtTtUuUuUuUu'+
    'UuUuWwYyYZzZzZz.';

function stripaccents(str){
    var answer='';
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        var ch=str[i];
        var chindex=ch.charCodeAt(0)-192;   // Index of character code in the strip string
        if(chindex>=0 && chindex<stripstring.length){
            // Character is within our table, so we can strip the accent...
            var outch=stripstring.charAt(chindex);
            // ...unless it was shown as a '.'
            if(outch!='.')ch=outch;
        }
        answer+=ch;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this answer might easily outperform the regexp answers by a lot. You should try doing a benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a user defined function to the [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, and in this user defined function use [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
function myCompareFunction(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}

var values = ["pêches", "épinards", "tomates", "fraises"];

// WRONG: ["fraises", "pêches", "tomates", "épinards"]
values.sort();

 // **GOOD**: ["épinards", "fraises", "pêches", "tomates"]
values.sort(myCompareFunction);
```

Comment: Hm, the array `["ép", "ep", "fp"]` is sorted as `["ep", "fp", "ép"]`. Do you happen to know why the letter `f` is between the letters `e` and `è`?

Comment: Hmmm damn, I tested in google chrome and it fails there. In Firefox works well.

Answer (score 1):

I used string.js's [latinise()](https://github.com/jprichardson/string.js#--latinise) method, which lets you do it like this:

```
var output = S(input).latinise().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
function removeAccents(strAccents){
    strAccents = strAccents.split('');
    strAccentsOut = new Array();
    strAccentsLen = strAccents.length;
    var accents = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
    var accentsOut = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','a','a','a','a','a','a','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','o','o','o','o','o','o','E','E','E','E','e','e','e','e','e','C','c','D','I','I','I','I','i','i','i','i','U','U','U','U','u','u','u','u','N','n','S','s','Y','y','y','Z','z'];
    for (var y = 0; y < strAccentsLen; y++) {
        if (accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]) != -1) {
            strAccentsOut[y] = accentsOut[accents.indexOf(strAccents[y])];
        }
        else
            strAccentsOut[y] = strAccents[y];
    }
    strAccentsOut = strAccentsOut.join('');
    return strAccentsOut;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you caught them all? (`čŘůľě`)

Comment: `ăĂâÂțȚţŢșȘşŞ` You gotta catch 'em all :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.legal_name = $sanitize($scope.legal_name);
    console.log("Name before function...",$scope.legal_name);

    var str = "";
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.legal_name.length; i++) {
        var charName = $scope.legal_name.charAt(i);
        if((charName == '&') && ($scope.legal_name.charAt(i + 1) == '#')){
            var count = 0;
            var subString = "";
            while(true) {
                if(($scope.legal_name.charCodeAt(i + 2 + count) > 47) && ($scope.legal_name.charCodeAt(i + 1 + count) < 58 )) {
                    subString = subString + $scope.legal_name.charAt(i + 2 + count);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    if(subString.length > 0) {
                        var value = parseInt(subString);
                        str = str + String.fromCharCode(value);
                        i = i + 1 + count; 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }               
        } else {
            str = str + charName;
        }
    }
    $scope.legal_name = str;
    console.log("Name After function...",str);
```

Comment: Please explain your code. This would make the answer even better!

Comment: u will put any value in "$scope.legal_name" like :
$scope.legal_name = P&#256n&#256m&#256 it will convert all ASCII values into there respective characters  "Pánámá"

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me. JavaScript, Google Apps Scripts, GAS

```
function normalizetext(text) {
  var weird = 'öüóőúéáàűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁÀŰÍçÇ!@£$%^&*()_+?/*."';
var normalized = 'ouooueaauiOUOOUEAAUIcC                 ';
var idoff = -1,new_text = '';
var lentext = text.toString().length -1

for (i = 0; i <= lentext; i++) {
idoff = weird.search(text.charAt(i));
if (idoff == -1) {
new_text = new_text + text.charAt(i);
} else {
new_text = new_text + normalized.charAt(idoff);
}

}
return new_text;

}
```

Comment: This works only if all your characters are in that string. Also, high time/memory complexity but if you don’t do heavy work with it that’s fine.

Answer (score 0):

My take, for removing all accents and special characters. I've mixed Lewis Diamond's elegant accent removal method with the community wiki's fast character replace for the rest of the characters. The result is an Ascii string.

```js
function convertToAscii(string) {
    const unicodeToAsciiMap = {'Ⱥ':'A','Æ':'AE','Ꜻ':'AV','Ɓ':'B','Ƀ':'B','Ƃ':'B','Ƈ':'C','Ȼ':'C','Ɗ':'D','ǲ':'D','ǅ':'D','Đ':'D','Ƌ':'D','Ǆ':'DZ','Ɇ':'E','Ꝫ':'ET','Ƒ':'F','Ɠ':'G','Ǥ':'G','Ⱨ':'H','Ħ':'H','Ɨ':'I','Ꝺ':'D','Ꝼ':'F','Ᵹ':'G','Ꞃ':'R','Ꞅ':'S','Ꞇ':'T','Ꝭ':'IS','Ɉ':'J','Ⱪ':'K','Ꝃ':'K','Ƙ':'K','Ꝁ':'K','Ꝅ':'K','Ƚ':'L','Ⱡ':'L','Ꝉ':'L','Ŀ':'L','Ɫ':'L','ǈ':'L','Ł':'L','Ɱ':'M','Ɲ':'N','Ƞ':'N','ǋ':'N','Ꝋ':'O','Ꝍ':'O','Ɵ':'O','Ø':'O','Ƣ':'OI','Ɛ':'E','Ɔ':'O','Ȣ':'OU','Ꝓ':'P','Ƥ':'P','Ꝕ':'P','Ᵽ':'P','Ꝑ':'P','Ꝙ':'Q','Ꝗ':'Q','Ɍ':'R','Ɽ':'R','Ꜿ':'C','Ǝ':'E','Ⱦ':'T','Ƭ':'T','Ʈ':'T','Ŧ':'T','Ɐ':'A','Ꞁ':'L','Ɯ':'M','Ʌ':'V','Ꝟ':'V','Ʋ':'V','Ⱳ':'W','Ƴ':'Y','Ỿ':'Y','Ɏ':'Y','Ⱬ':'Z','Ȥ':'Z','Ƶ':'Z','Œ':'OE','ᴀ':'A','ᴁ':'AE','ʙ':'B','ᴃ':'B','ᴄ':'C','ᴅ':'D','ᴇ':'E','ꜰ':'F','ɢ':'G','ʛ':'G','ʜ':'H','ɪ':'I','ʁ':'R','ᴊ':'J','ᴋ':'K','ʟ':'L','ᴌ':'L','ᴍ':'M','ɴ':'N','ᴏ':'O','ɶ':'OE','ᴐ':'O','ᴕ':'OU','ᴘ':'P','ʀ':'R','ᴎ':'N','ᴙ':'R','ꜱ':'S','ᴛ':'T','ⱻ':'E','ᴚ':'R','ᴜ':'U','ᴠ':'V','ᴡ':'W','ʏ':'Y','ᴢ':'Z','ᶏ':'a','ẚ':'a','ⱥ':'a','æ':'ae','ꜻ':'av','ɓ':'b','ᵬ':'b','ᶀ':'b','ƀ':'b','ƃ':'b','ɵ':'o','ɕ':'c','ƈ':'c','ȼ':'c','ȡ':'d','ɗ':'d','ᶑ':'d','ᵭ':'d','ᶁ':'d','đ':'d','ɖ':'d','ƌ':'d','ı':'i','ȷ':'j','ɟ':'j','ʄ':'j','ǆ':'dz','ⱸ':'e','ᶒ':'e','ɇ':'e','ꝫ':'et','ƒ':'f','ᵮ':'f','ᶂ':'f','ɠ':'g','ᶃ':'g','ǥ':'g','ⱨ':'h','ɦ':'h','ħ':'h','ƕ':'hv','ᶖ':'i','ɨ':'i','ꝺ':'d','ꝼ':'f','ᵹ':'g','ꞃ':'r','ꞅ':'s','ꞇ':'t','ꝭ':'is','ʝ':'j','ɉ':'j','ⱪ':'k','ꝃ':'k','ƙ':'k','ᶄ':'k','ꝁ':'k','ꝅ':'k','ƚ':'l','ɬ':'l','ȴ':'l','ⱡ':'l','ꝉ':'l','ŀ':'l','ɫ':'l','ᶅ':'l','ɭ':'l','ł':'l','ſ':'s','ẜ':'s','ẝ':'s','ɱ':'m','ᵯ':'m','ᶆ':'m','ȵ':'n','ɲ':'n','ƞ':'n','ᵰ':'n','ᶇ':'n','ɳ':'n','ꝋ':'o','ꝍ':'o','ⱺ':'o','ø':'o','ƣ':'oi','ɛ':'e','ᶓ':'e','ɔ':'o','ᶗ':'o','ȣ':'ou','ꝓ':'p','ƥ':'p','ᵱ':'p','ᶈ':'p','ꝕ':'p','ᵽ':'p','ꝑ':'p','ꝙ':'q','ʠ':'q','ɋ':'q','ꝗ':'q','ɾ':'r','ᵳ':'r','ɼ':'r','ᵲ':'r','ᶉ':'r','ɍ':'r','ɽ':'r','ↄ':'c','ꜿ':'c','ɘ':'e','ɿ':'r','ʂ':'s','ᵴ':'s','ᶊ':'s','ȿ':'s','ɡ':'g','ᴑ':'o','ᴓ':'o','ᴝ':'u','ȶ':'t','ⱦ':'t','ƭ':'t','ᵵ':'t','ƫ':'t','ʈ':'t','ŧ':'t','ᵺ':'th','ɐ':'a','ᴂ':'ae','ǝ':'e','ᵷ':'g','ɥ':'h','ʮ':'h','ʯ':'h','ᴉ':'i','ʞ':'k','ꞁ':'l','ɯ':'m','ɰ':'m','ᴔ':'oe','ɹ':'r','ɻ':'r','ɺ':'r','ⱹ':'r','ʇ':'t','ʌ':'v','ʍ':'w','ʎ':'y','ᶙ':'u','ᵫ':'ue','ꝸ':'um','ⱴ':'v','ꝟ':'v','ʋ':'v','ᶌ':'v','ⱱ':'v','ⱳ':'w','ᶍ':'x','ƴ':'y','ỿ':'y','ɏ':'y','ʑ':'z','ⱬ':'z','ȥ':'z','ᵶ':'z','ᶎ':'z','ʐ':'z','ƶ':'z','ɀ':'z','œ':'oe','ₓ':'x'};
    const stringWithoutAccents = string.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
    return stringWithoutAccents.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, character => unicodeToAsciiMap[character] || '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're also interesting in converting Greek characters to Latin, I've included the Greek alhpabet along with some *digraphs*; it can also be used for a form of combined *orthographic* and *phonetic* *[Greeklish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeklish)*.

Also, this version accepts optional options with:

- `override` Object {replace:string -> search:regex, ...}
  It overrides the default replacements
- `ignore` Array<string | regex> | string
  Ignores the list items which can be strings or regular expressions

```js
const defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = {
  '1' : /[\u00B9]/g,
  '2' : /[\u00B2]/g,
  '3' : /[\u00B3]/g,

  'AU': /\u0391\u03A5|\u0386\u03A5/g,
  'EU': /\u0395\u03A5|\u0388\u03A5/g,
  'OU': /\u039F\u03A5|\u039F\u038E/g,
  'au': /\u03B1\u03C5|\u03AC\u03C5/g,
  'eu': /\u03B5\u03C5|\u03AD\u03C5/g,
  'ou': /\u03BF\u03C5|\u03BF\u03CD/g,
  'Au': /\u0391\u03C5|\u0386\u03C5/g,
  'Eu': /\u0395\u03C5|\u0388\u03C5/g,
  'Ou': /\u039F\u03C5|\u039F\u03CD/g,

  'A' : /[\u0391\u0386\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]/g,
  'AA': /[\uA732]/g,
  'AE': /[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]/g,
  'AF': /[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]/g,
  'AO': /[\uA734]/g,
  'AU': /[\uA736]/g,
  'AV': /[\uA738\uA73A]/g,
  'AY': /[\uA73C]/g,
  'B' : /[\u0392\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]/g,
  'C' : /[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]/g,
  'D' : /[\u00D0\u0394\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]/g,
  'DZ': /[\u01F1\u01C4]/g,
  'Dz': /[\u01F2\u01C5]/g,
  'E' : /[\u0395\u0388\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]/g,
  'F' : /[\u03A6\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]/g,
  'G' : /[\u0393\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]/g,
  'H' : /[\u0397\u0389\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]/g,
  'I' : /[\u0399\u038A\u03AA\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]/g,
  'J' : /[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]/g,
  'K' : /[\u039A\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]/g,
  'KS': /[\u039E]/g,
  'L' : /[\u039B\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]/g,
  'LJ': /[\u01C7]/g,
  'Lj': /[\u01C8]/g,
  'M' : /[\u039C\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]/g,
  'N' : /[\u039D\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]/g,
  'NJ': /[\u01CA]/g,
  'Nj': /[\u01CB]/g,
  'O' : /[\u038C\u039F\u03A9\u038F\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]/g,
  'OE': /[\u0152]/g,
  'OI': /[\u01A2]/g,
  'OO': /[\uA74E]/g,
  'OU': /[\u0222]/g,
  'P' : /[\u03A0\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]/g,
  'PS': /[\u03A8]/g,
  'Q' : /[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]/g,
  'R' : /[\u03A1\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]/g,
  'S' : /[\u03A3\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]/g,
  'T' : /[\u03A4\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]/g,
  'TZ': /[\uA728]/g,
  'TH': /[\u0398]/g,
  'U' : /[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]/g,
  'V' : /[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]/g,
  'VY': /[\uA760]/g,
  'W' : /[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]/g,
  'X' : /[\u03A7\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]/g,
  'Y' : /[\u03A5\u038E\u03AB\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]/g,
  'Z' : /[\u0396\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]/g,
  'a' : /[\u03B1\u03AC\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]/g,
  'aa': /[\uA733]/g,
  'ae': /[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3]/g,
  'ao': /[\uA735]/g,
  'au': /[\uA737]/g,
  'av': /[\uA739\uA73B]/g,
  'ay': /[\uA73D]/g,
  'b' : /[\u03B2\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]/g,
  'c' : /[\u00A9\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]/g,
  'd' : /[\u03B4\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]/g,
  'dz': /[\u01F3\u01C6]/g,
  'e' : /[\u20AC\u00F0\u03B5\u03AD\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]/g,
  'f' : /[\u03C6\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]/g,
  'g' : /[\u03B3\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]/g,
  'h' : /[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]/g,
  'hv': /[\u0195]/g,
  'i' : /[\u03B9\u03AF\u03CA\u0390\u03B7\u03AE\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]/g,
  'j' : /[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]/g,
  'k' : /[\u03BA\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]/g,
  'ks': /[\u03BE]/g,
  'l' : /[\u03BB\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]/g,
  'lj': /[\u01C9]/g,
  'm' : /[\u03BC\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]/g,
  'n' : /[\u03BD\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]/g,
  'nj': /[\u01CC]/g,
  'o' : /[\u03C9\u03CE\u03CC\u03BF\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]/g,
  'oe': /[\u0153]/g,
  'oi': /[\u01A3]/g,
  'ou': /[\u0223]/g,
  'oo': /[\uA74F]/g,
  'p' : /[\u03C0\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]/g,
  'ps': /[\u03C8]/g,
  'q' : /[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]/g,
  'r' : /[\u00AE\u03C1\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]/g,
  's' : /[\u03C2\u03C3\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]/g,
  't' : /[\u03C4\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]/g,
  'tz': /[\uA729]/g,
  'th': /[\u03B8]/g,
  'u' : /[\u00B5\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]/g,
  'v' : /[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]/g,
  'vy': /[\uA761]/g,
  'w' : /[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]/g,
  'x' : /[\u03C7\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]/g,
  'y' : /[\u03C5\u03CD\u03CB\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]/g,
  'z' : /[\u03B6\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]/g,
};

function removeAccent(str, {
  override,
  ignore
} = {}) {
  // Function to convert strings to unicode char code escape strings
  const toHex = s => s.split('').map(c => `\\u${c.charCodeAt().toString(16).padStart(4, "0")}`).join('');

  const useToIgnore = ignore && typeof(ignore) === 'string' ? ignore.split('') : ignore;

  // For every ignore item, replace it with {\uXXXX} so we'll get it back when we finish
  let useStr = useToIgnore ? 
    useToIgnore.reduce((acc, cur) => 
      acc.replace(cur, m => `{${toHex(m)}}`), str) :
    str;

  // Loop through overrides first
  if (override) {
    for (const base in override) {
      useStr = useStr.replace(override[base], base);
    }
  }

  // Loop through the defaults
  for (const base in defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap) {
    useStr = useStr.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[base], base);
  }

  // Restore ignored mappings
  return useToIgnore ?
    useStr.replace(
      /\{?(\\u([0-9a-f]*))\}?/g, 
      (m, g1, hex) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16))
    ) :
    useStr;
}

// Helper function to convert and print the subjects
RegExp.prototype.toJSON = RegExp.prototype.toString;
function print([str, options]) {
  const subjects = document.getElementById('subjects');
  const result = document.createElement('div');
  result.className = 'result';

  if (options) {
    const opts = document.createElement('div');
    opts.textContent = JSON.stringify(options) + "\n";
    result.appendChild(opts);
  }

  const texts = document.createTextNode(`›  ${str}\n‹  ${removeAccent(str, options)}\n`);
  result.appendChild(texts);
  subjects.appendChild(result);
}

// The subjects with some options
const subjects = [
  ["Mon café est plein de caféïne"],
  ["Τι αξία έχει ο γάμος στην αγάπη μας μπροστά, είναι κι άλλοι παντρεμένοι κι όμως ζούνε χωριστά. - Ζαμπέτας"],
  ["ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜ ùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž"],
  ["¹²³áàâãäåaaaÀÁÂÃÄÅAAAÆccç©CCÇÐÐèéêëeeeeeÈÊËEEEEE€g           GiìíîïìiiiÌÍÎÏÌIIIlLnnñNNÑòóôõöoooøÒÓÔÕÖOOOØŒr®RšsßŠS ùúûüuuuuÙÚÛÜUUUUýÿÝŸžzzŽZZ", {
    ignore: ['€', 'Ð', 'Æ']
  }],
  [
  "Ο λούτσος του Αυγούστου", {
    ignore: [/\u03BF\u03C5|\u03BF\u03CD/g]
  }],
  ["Η χθεσινή της Κυριακής"],
  ["Η χθεσινή της Κυριακής", {
    override: { 'H': /[ΗΉ]/g, 'h': /[ηή]/g }
  }]
];

// Print all subjects
subjects.forEach(print);
```

```css
.result {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgrey;
}

.result:last-child {
  border:0;
}

.result > div {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="subjects"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the wiki answer and I translated it into typescript static class, for people that come from for example angular.

```
export class DiacriticsRemover {

  private static diacriticsMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

  private static defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
    {
      base: 'A',
      letters: '\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'
    },
    {
      base: 'AA',
      letters: '\uA732'
    },
    {
      base: 'AE',
      letters: '\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'
    },
    {
      base: 'AO',
      letters: '\uA734'
    },
    {
      base: 'AU',
      letters: '\uA736'
    },
    {
      base: 'AV',
      letters: '\uA738\uA73A'
    },
    {
      base: 'AY',
      letters: '\uA73C'
    },
    {
      base: 'B',
      letters: '\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'
    },
    {
      base: 'C',
      letters: '\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'
    },
    {
      base: 'D',
      letters: '\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0'
    },
    {
      base: 'DZ',
      letters: '\u01F1\u01C4'
    },
    {
      base: 'Dz',
      letters: '\u01F2\u01C5'
    },
    {
      base: 'E',
      letters: '\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'
    },
    {
      base: 'F',
      letters: '\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'
    },
    {
      base: 'G',
      letters: '\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'
    },
    {
      base: 'H',
      letters: '\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'
    },
    {
      base: 'I',
      letters: '\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'
    },
    {
      base: 'J',
      letters: '\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'
    },
    {
      base: 'K',
      letters: '\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'
    },
    {
      base: 'L',
      letters: '\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'
    },
    {
      base: 'LJ',
      letters: '\u01C7'
    },
    {
      base: 'Lj',
      letters: '\u01C8'
    },
    {
      base: 'M',
      letters: '\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'
    },
    {
      base: 'N',
      letters: '\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'
    },
    {
      base: 'NJ',
      letters: '\u01CA'
    },
    {
      base: 'Nj',
      letters: '\u01CB'
    },
    {
      base: 'O',
      letters: '\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'
    },
    {
      base: 'OI',
      letters: '\u01A2'
    },
    {
      base: 'OO',
      letters: '\uA74E'
    },
    {
      base: 'OU',
      letters: '\u0222'
    },
    {
      base: 'OE',
      letters: '\u008C\u0152'
    },
    {
      base: 'oe',
      letters: '\u009C\u0153'
    },
    {
      base: 'P',
      letters: '\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'
    },
    {
      base: 'Q',
      letters: '\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'
    },
    {
      base: 'R',
      letters: '\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'
    },
    {
      base: 'S',
      letters: '\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'
    },
    {
      base: 'T',
      letters: '\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'
    },
    {
      base: 'TZ',
      letters: '\uA728'
    },
    {
      base: 'U',
      letters: '\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'
    },
    {
      base: 'V',
      letters: '\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'
    },
    {
      base: 'VY',
      letters: '\uA760'
    },
    {
      base: 'W',
      letters: '\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'
    },
    {
      base: 'X',
      letters: '\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'
    },
    {
      base: 'Y',
      letters: '\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'
    },
    {
      base: 'Z',
      letters: '\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'
    },
    {
      base: 'a',
      letters: '\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'
    },
    {
      base: 'aa',
      letters: '\uA733'
    },
    {
      base: 'ae',
      letters: '\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'
    },
    {
      base: 'ao',
      letters: '\uA735'
    },
    {
      base: 'au',
      letters: '\uA737'
    },
    {
      base: 'av',
      letters: '\uA739\uA73B'
    },
    {
      base: 'ay',
      letters: '\uA73D'
    },
    {
      base: 'b',
      letters: '\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'
    },
    {
      base: 'c',
      letters: '\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'
    },
    {
      base: 'd',
      letters: '\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'
    },
    {
      base: 'dz',
      letters: '\u01F3\u01C6'
    },
    {
      base: 'e',
      letters: '\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'
    },
    {
      base: 'f',
      letters: '\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'
    },
    {
      base: 'g',
      letters: '\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'
    },
    {
      base: 'h',
      letters: '\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'
    },
    {
      base: 'hv',
      letters: '\u0195'
    },
    {
      base: 'i',
      letters: '\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'
    },
    {
      base: 'j',
      letters: '\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'
    },
    {
      base: 'k',
      letters: '\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'
    },
    {
      base: 'l',
      letters: '\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'
    },
    {
      base: 'lj',
      letters: '\u01C9'
    },
    {
      base: 'm',
      letters: '\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'
    },
    {
      base: 'n',
      letters: '\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'
    },
    {
      base: 'nj',
      letters: '\u01CC'
    },
    {
      base: 'o',
      letters: '\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'
    },
    {
      base: 'oi',
      letters: '\u01A3'
    },
    {
      base: 'ou',
      letters: '\u0223'
    },
    {
      base: 'oo',
      letters: '\uA74F'
    },
    {
      base: 'p',
      letters: '\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'
    },
    {
      base: 'q',
      letters: '\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'
    },
    {
      base: 'r',
      letters: '\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'
    },
    {
      base: 's',
      letters: '\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'
    },
    {
      base: 't',
      letters: '\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'
    },
    {
      base: 'tz',
      letters: '\uA729'
    },
    {
      base: 'u',
      letters: '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'
    },
    {
      base: 'v',
      letters: '\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'
    },
    {
      base: 'vy',
      letters: '\uA761'
    },
    {
      base: 'w',
      letters: '\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'
    },
    {
      base: 'x',
      letters: '\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'
    },
    {
      base: 'y',
      letters: '\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'
    },
    {
      base: 'z',
      letters: '\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'
    }
  ];

  private static isSetUp = false;

  public static removeDiacritics(text: string): string {
    if (!this.isSetUp) {
      this.setUp();
    }

    return text.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, (a: string) => this.diacriticsMap.get(a) || a);
  }

  private static setUp(): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
    for (let i = 0; i < this.defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
      const letters = this.defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters;

      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
      for (let j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
        this.diacriticsMap.set(letters[j], this.defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base);
      }
    }
    this.isSetUp = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removing macrons from te reo Māori language**
For anyone who came here to remove macrons from te reo Māori language.
Note: Stackblitz removed the single quotes off the map keys when I formatted the code - they must be confident it is OK. [Subset of this code thank you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript/9667752#9667752)

```js
'use strict';

    var macronMap = {
      ā: 'a',
      ē: 'e',
      ī: 'i',
      ō: 'o',
      ū: 'u',
      Ā: 'A',
      Ē: 'E',
      Ī: 'I',
      Ō: 'O',
      Ū: 'U',
    };

    function deMacron(str) {
      return str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\[\] ]/g, function (char) {
        return macronMap[char] || char;
      });
    }
    function macronFree(str) {
      return str === deMacron(str);
    }

    console.assert(
      'a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U' === deMacron('ā, ē, ī, ō, ū, Ā, Ē, Ī, Ō, Ū')
    );        
    console.assert(macronFree('a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U'));       
    console.assert(!macronFree('ā, ē, ī, ō, ū, Ā, Ē, Ī, Ō, Ū'));
    document.body.append(deMacron('ā, ē, ī, ō, ū, Ā, Ē, Ī, Ō, Ū'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use localCompare https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

```
const a = 'réservé'; // With accents, lowercase
const b = 'RESERVE'; // No accents, uppercase

console.log(a.localeCompare(b));
// Expected output: 1
console.log(a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }));
// Expected output: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create regex's in multiple ways. Using the new `RegExp`-constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp("[a-z]", "ig") //(string pattern, string modifiers)
```

Or using the regex literal notation:

```
var re = /[a-z]/ig; // /pattern/modifiers
```

You have mixed the two.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

All the above isn't working with decomposed character as used on Mac OS.
In order to remove diacritics in that case it is more simple :

```
r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g),"")
```

see comment from Olivier Miakinen on :
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fr.comp.lang.regexp/6IGJTbedGTM/G0sB2kAsR34J
(posted in french)