# Detecting if a character is a letter

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

Given a set of words, I need to put them in an hash keyed on the first letter of the word.
I have words = {}, with keys A..Z and 0 for numbers and symbols.
I was doing something like

```
var firstLetter = name.charAt(0);
    firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();

if (firstLetter < "A" || firstLetter > "Z") {
    firstLetter = "0";
}
if (words[firstLetter] === undefined) {
    words[firstLetter] = [];
} 
words[firstLetter].push(name);
```

but this fails with dieresis and other chars, like in the word **Ärzteversorgung**.
That word is put in the "0" array, how could I put it in the "A" array?

Comment: Do you only want to have characters like Ä detected as letters, or do you want to have Ä detected as if it were an A?

Comment: Ä is not an A. You will need a mapping of characters with accents to without accents.

Comment: you have to map for Ä and other alphabets of this character too. like you are doing for 0 1 2 3..... and abc etc.

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863800/replacing-diacritics-in-javascript

Comment: Would using a regex test, like `/[\w\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]/.test(firstLetter)` be appropriate?

Comment: @HeitorChang this duplicate have better answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings

Comment: I need to map Ä as A. The link suggested by ajax333221 has answers that solve to my question, as you have to transform the string using some kind of map

Comment: you may want to remove accents & then do a simple [a-z] check. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not consider international characters to be "word characters". But you can do it with the regular expression below:

```
var firstLetter = name.charAt(0);
firstLetter = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
if (!firstLetter.match(/^\wÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜäëïöüçÇßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð$/)) {
    firstLetter = "0";
}
if (words[firstLetter] === undefined) {
    words[firstLetter] = [];
} 
words[firstLetter].push(name);
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use this to test if a character is *likely to be* a letter:

```
var firstLetter = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
if( firstLetter.toLowerCase() != firstLetter) {
    // it's a letter
}
else {
    // it's a symbol
}
```

This works because JavaScript already has a mapping for lowercase to uppercase letters (and vice versa), so if a character is unchanged by `toLowerCase()` then it's not in the letter table.

Comment: An interesting trick, but as you emphasize, it works just “likely”. But it might be used if you add ad hoc checks for all the characters that may appear and that cause a wrong result in the simple test.

In the Latin 1 range, the following characters get misclassified: º and ª (masculine and feminine ordinal indicators), sharp ß (probably the most relevant character here), and debatably the micro sign µ (formally a letter in Unicode, compatibility equivalent to Greek letter mu, but widely understood as a special character rather than a letter).

Comment: It only works for characters in bicameral scripts, i.e. writing systems that make uppercase/lowercase distinction; most scripts don’t (e.g., Hebrew, Devanagari, Chinese).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Yes there are cons and the pros are the speed of the check. this can processed much faster than anything else, and English will likely (should) be the only language most people will need)

Comment: @vsync, the question mentions the sample word “Ärzteversorgung”. It isn’t English. Typically if people only think of English, they don’t even ask this question—they just assume that `[A-Za-z]` covers all letters.

Comment: Questions in Stackoverflow sometimes means nothing because I came here from Google and what the OP asked for is not what the title suggests, therefore it's important to cover the answers for the people who do come here from Google for answers.

Comment: As of 2020: In a latin script you can use the uppercase/lowercase comparison to mark a character as a letter. Try this:  'ß'.toUpperCase() // ==> 'SS', 'ſ'.toUpperCase() // ==> 'S'. Even in Greek: 'µ'.toUpperCase() // ==> 'Μ' (for \u00B5 as well as \u03BC). Only for the ordinal indicators the lowercase === uppercase.

Answer (score 5):

Try converting the character to its uppercase and lowercase and check to see if there's a difference. Only letter characters change when they are converted to their respective upper and lower case (numbers, punctuation marks, etc. don't). Below is a sample function using this concept in mind:

```
function isALetter(charVal)
{
    if( charVal.toUpperCase() != charVal.toLowerCase() )
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The expression `"Á" == "á"` will always return `false`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.charCodeAt(0);` to get the position in the ASCII Chart and then do some checks.

The ranges you are looking for are probably 65-90, 97-122, 128-154, 160-165 (inclusive), but double check this by viewing the [ASCII Chart](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/files/ascii.htm)

Something like this

```
if((x>64&&x<91)||(x>96&&x<123)||(x>127&&x<155)||(x>159&&x<166))
```

Where `x` is the Char Code

Comment: I don't know, [charCodeAt MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) says _"Unicode code points range from 0 to 1,114,111"_

Comment: @jnrbsn No it won't... ASCII does not cover for all of what is considered a letter in every language

Comment: @ajax333221 There are some valid code points which are not printable characters

Comment: this works for bytes, but not for characters... a character can be more than one byte

Answer (score 2):

This is fortunately now possible without external libraries. Straight from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```
let story = "It’s the Cheshire Cat: now I shall have somebody to talk to.";

// Most explicit form
story.match(/\p{General_Category=Letter}/gu);

// It is not mandatory to use the property name for General categories
story.match(/\p{Letter}/gu);
```