# How to check for first letter should be uppercase in JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning javascript and Regex  and trying to validate a input if the first letter in the string is in uppercase.

my current Regex is : `var patt1=/[A-Z]{4}$/;`

but this is validating the string if all the four letters are in uppercase not the first letter only.

Any idea how to make it work.

Note :  I am also checking the input should be 4 letter long.

Comment: There is [enormous results](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Checking+first+letter+is+uppercase+wth+regex&rlz=2C1CHWA_enIN0536IN0536&oq=Checking+first+letter+is+uppercase+wth+regex&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6881j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you will get, when you google your title.

Comment: Where does the 4 come from ? Did you want to validate the length of the string ?

Comment: @RohitJain How to google?

Comment: @Aerovistae. Jesus Christ. :-\

Comment: Maybe I should google it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that by "uppercase" you mean a letter in A-Z, then you may use

```
var isFirstLetterUppercase = /^[A-Z]/.test(yourString);
```

The idea here (and in similar cases) is to use `^` which matches the start of the string.

If you also want to check the length of the string, you may use :

```
var isOK = /^[A-Z].{3}$/.test(yourString);
```

Here, `.{3}` means 3 characters and `$` is the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it can test the first letter, but i am also checking the input should be 4 letter long.

Comment: @user2684945 let's just say that a four-letter string that starts with an uppercase is a string that starts with an uppercase, follows with tree more characters and then ends. One more hint: the end-of-string anchor is `$`.

Comment: @dystroy Thanks a lot the dot{.} is very impressive.

Comment: "Provided that by "uppercase" you mean a letter in A-Z..." Sorry to disagree, but that's just setting yourself up for a bug when you have to deal with non-ASCII characters such as the city of Überlingen in Germany. There is an easy way to correctly determine if a character or string is uppercase, and it would be better to use that.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I warn against that but it totally depends on the requirement. And as OP is explicitly "learning regex", I guess a non regex based answer wouldn't be satisfying...

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using an A-Z test in a regular expression is that A-Z are not the only uppercase letters.

Consider the city of **Überlingen** in Germany. The first letter certainly is uppercase, but it is *not* in the range A to Z. Try it in the JavaScript console:

```
/^[A-Z]/.test('Überlingen');  // logs false - oops!
```

Now here is where it gets a bit tricky. What exactly does it mean for a letter to be uppercase? In English it's simple: A-Z vs. a-z. In German, Ü (for example) is uppercase and ü is lowercase. For languages like these that have both uppercase and lowercase characters, you can test if a character is uppercase by converting it to *lowercase* with the `.toLowerCase()` method and comparing that with the original. If they are different, the original was uppercase. If they are the same, the original was either a lowercase character or a character that doesn't have uppercase and lowercase versions (e.g. a number or punctuation mark).

```
// 'char' is a string containing a single character
function isUpperCase( char ) {
    return char !== char.toLowerCase();
}
```

Now you can test if the first character of a string is uppercase by extracting that character with `.charAt()` and calling `isUpperCase()`:

```
function beginsWithUpperCase( string ) {
    return isUpperCase( string.charAt(0) );
}
```

This works correctly for the German city:

```
beginsWithUpperCase( 'Überlingen' );  // logs `true`.
```

And now, since we're not using a regular expression at all, if you want to check the string length, merely use the `.length` property:

```
function fourCharactersWithFirstUpperCase( string ) {
    return string.length === 4  &&  beginsWithUpperCase( string );
}

fourCharactersWithFirstUpperCase( 'über' );  // logs false
fourCharactersWithFirstUpperCase( 'Über' );  // logs true
fourCharactersWithFirstUpperCase( 'Überlingen' );  // logs false
```

So we're in good shape for languages that have both uppercase and lowercase versions of the same character. But what about languages that don't *have* uppercase vs. lowercase characters? Then this code would return `false` for any string.

I don't have a good solution for that off the top of my head; you'd have to think about how you want to handle that case.

BTW if you really want to try this with a regular expression, there's a possible approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708129/1202830). Instead of just testing for A-Z, you could list *all* of the uppercase letters in the languages you may have to deal with. Adapting the regex from that answer, it might look like this:

```
function beginsWithUpperCase( string ) {
    return /^[A-ZÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜäëïöüçÇßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð]/.test( string );
}
```

Of course that raises the question of whether we've accurately listed all of the uppercase characters for every language!